# Very large matrices using Python and NumPy

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

[NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) is an extremely useful library, and from using it I've found that it's capable of handling matrices which are quite large (10000 x 10000) easily, but begins to struggle with anything much larger (trying to create a matrix of 50000 x 50000 fails). Obviously, this is because of the massive memory requirements.

Is there is a way to create huge matrices natively in NumPy (say 1 million by 1 million) in some way (without having several terrabytes of RAM)?

Answer (score 94):

PyTables and NumPy are the way to go.

PyTables will store the data on disk in HDF format, with optional compression. My datasets often get 10x compression, which is handy when dealing with tens or hundreds of millions of rows. It's also very fast; my 5 year old laptop can crunch through data doing SQL-like GROUP BY aggregation at 1,000,000 rows/second. Not bad for a Python-based solution!

Accessing the data as a NumPy recarray again is as simple as:

```
data = table[row_from:row_to]
```

The HDF library takes care of reading in the relevant chunks of data and converting to NumPy.

Comment: So you still have to break the data up into chunks yourself for processing?  It's just a way to simplify the conversion to and from disk files?

Comment: Any chance you could expand your answer with a bit more clarity and some examples?

Comment: For now, package `h5py` can also access an HDF5 object like a NumPy ndarray. `h5py` APIs is probably more alike to the NumPy. Also see difference (and connections) between `h5py` and `pytables`. https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-difference-between-h5py-and-pytables

Answer (score 62):

`numpy.array`s are meant to live in memory.  If you want to work with matrices larger than your RAM, you have to work around that.  There are at least two approaches you can follow:

1. **Try a more efficient matrix representation** that exploits any special structure that your matrices have.  For example, as others have already pointed out, there are efficient data structures for sparse matrices (matrices with lots of zeros), like [`scipy.sparse.csc_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html).
2. **Modify your algorithm to work on submatrices**.  You can read from disk only the matrix blocks that are currently being used in computations.  Algorithms designed to run on clusters usually work blockwise, since the data is scatted across different computers, and passed by only when needed.  For example, [the Fox algorithm for matrix multiplication (PDF file)](http://facultyfp.salisbury.edu/taanastasio/COSC490/Fall03/Lectures/FoxMM/example.pdf).

Comment: 3- Step-in the Big Data paradigm and study solutions like MapReduce

Comment: For number 2, how do you decide how big to make your chunks? Is there a way to measure the amount of free memory and size your chunks based on that?

Answer (score 31):

You should be able to use numpy.memmap to memory map a file on disk.  With newer python and 64-bit machine, you should have the necessary address space, without loading everything into memory.  The OS should handle only keep part of the file in memory.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use it to do something that can't fit in memory?

Answer (score 24):

To handle sparse matrices, you need the `scipy` package that sits on top of `numpy` -- see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) for more details about the sparse-matrix options that `scipy` gives you.

Answer (score 11):

Stefano Borini's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053928/python-numpy-very-large-matrices/1053953#1053953) got me to look into how far along this sort of thing already is.

[This is it.](http://h5py.alfven.org/)  It appears to do basically what you want.  HDF5 will let you store very large datasets, and then access and use them in the same ways NumPy does.

Comment: A better choice might be PyTables.  It's higher level than the core HDF5 functionality (H5Py is little more than the low-level API accessible from Python).  Also last week's 2.2 beta has tools for this problem:
http://www.pytables.org/moin/ReleaseNotes/Release_2.2b1
Added Expr, a class [that] can evaluate expressions (like '3*a+4*b') that operate on arbitrary large arrays while optimizing the resources[...]. It is similar to the Numexpr package, but in addition to NumPy objects, it also accepts disk-based homogeneous arrays, like the Array, CArray, EArray and Column PyTables objects.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you're using a 64-bit operating system and a 64-bit version of Python/NumPy. Note that on 32-bit architectures you can address typically 3GB of memory (with about 1GB lost to memory mapped I/O and such).

With 64-bit and things arrays larger than the available RAM you can get away with virtual memory, though things will get slower if you have to swap. Also, memory maps (see numpy.memmap) are a way to work with huge files on disk without loading them into memory, but again, you need to have a 64-bit address space to work with for this to be of much use. PyTables will do most of this for you as well.

Comment: How do you setup virtual memory?

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit alpha, but http://blaze.pydata.org/ seems to be working on solving this.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes one simple solution is using a custom type for your matrix items. Based on the range of numbers you need, you can use a manual `dtype` and specially smaller for your items. Because Numpy considers the largest type for object by default this might be a helpful idea in many cases. Here is an example:

```
In [70]: a = np.arange(5)

In [71]: a[0].dtype
Out[71]: dtype('int64')

In [72]: a.nbytes
Out[72]: 40

In [73]: a = np.arange(0, 2, 0.5)

In [74]: a[0].dtype
Out[74]: dtype('float64')

In [75]: a.nbytes
Out[75]: 32
```

And with custom type:

```
In [80]: a = np.arange(5, dtype=np.int8)

In [81]: a.nbytes
Out[81]: 5

In [76]: a = np.arange(0, 2, 0.5, dtype=np.float16)

In [78]: a.nbytes
Out[78]: 8
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking how to handle a 2,500,000,000 element matrix without terabytes of RAM?

The way to handle 2 billion items without 8 billion bytes of RAM is by not keeping the matrix in memory.

That means much more sophisticated algorithms to fetch it from the file system in pieces.

Comment: Not true. If 99.99% (for a realistic example) of the elements are zero, then all of the data of the matrix can be kept in memory. There is no need to use up 4 bytes for every zero, when you can just store a list of `(row, column, value)` for those entries that do exist.

Comment: @EricWilson: Where in the question did it suggest the matrix was sparse?  I totally missed that.  Can you provide the quote?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when we deal with large matrices we implement them as [Sparse Matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).

I don't know if numpy supports sparse matrices but I found [this](http://www.scipy.org/SciPy_Tutorial) instead.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know about numpy, no, but I could be wrong.

I can propose you this alternative solution: write the matrix on the disk and access it in chunks. I suggest you the HDF5 file format. If you need it transparently, you can reimplement the ndarray interface to paginate your disk-stored matrix into memory. Be careful if you modify the data to sync them back on the disk.

Comment: What if I want to access a whole matrix of 57600 by 57600?