# Is there support for sparse matrices in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Is there support for sparse matrices in python?

Possibly in numpy or in scipy?

Comment: You can find answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053928/python-numpy-very-large-matrices

Answer (score 41):

**Yes.**

SciPi provides [scipy.sparse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html), a "2-D sparse matrix package for numeric data".

> There are seven available sparse matrix types:
>
> 1. csc_matrix: Compressed Sparse Column format
> 2. csr_matrix: Compressed Sparse Row format
> 3. bsr_matrix: Block Sparse Row format
> 4. lil_matrix: List of Lists format
> 5. dok_matrix: Dictionary of Keys format
> 6. coo_matrix: COOrdinate format (aka IJV, triplet format)
> 7. dia_matrix: DIAgonal format

Answer (score 5):

1. CVXOPT - [Sparse matrices](http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/userguide/matrices.html#sparse-matrices)
2. [Pysparse](http://pysparse.sourceforge.net/contents.html)