# Scipy or pandas for sparse matrix computations?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pandas

I have to compute massive similarity computations between vectors in a sparse matrix. What is currently the best tool, `scipy-sparse` or `pandas`, for this task?

Comment: I think you are looking for `scipy.sparse` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Comment: Yea, i meant `scipy.sparse` vs `pandas`. The numpy citation was a mistake.

Comment: `pandas` doesn't handle sparse arrays.  `scipy.sparse` handles sparse linear algebra, `pandas` doesn't have any of this functionality, as far as I know.

Comment: Do you know any alternatives to scipy sparse then? Could be in another language too.

Comment: Matlab (and Octave) has a good sparse capability.  And the ideas for both come from Fortran or C++ implementations.  Mostly these were developed with linear algebra problems in mind (i.e. solving linear equations like `A*x = b`, where `A` is a large sparse matrix.

Comment: pandas has had sparse support for several versions: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/sparse.html

Comment: See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623800/is-there-support-for-sparse-matrices-in-python

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found that both pandas and Scipy have structures to represent sparse matrix efficiently in memory. But none of them have out of box support for compute similarity between vectors like cosine, adjusted cosine, euclidean etc. Scipy support this on *dense* matrix only. For sparse, Scipy support dot products and others linear algebra basic operations.

Comment: If you need a dense mattrix, there's always dimensionality reduction (assuming it's the width of the matrix that's causing the matrix's size to be an issue).