# index milion row square matrix for fast access

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, blaze

I have some very large matrices (let say of the order of the million rows), that I **can not** keep in memory, and I would need to access to subsample of this matrix in descent time (less than a minute...).
I started looking at hdf5 and blaze in combination with numpy and pandas:

- http://web.datapark.io/yves/blaze.html
- http://blaze.pydata.org

But I found it a bit complicated, and I am not sure if it is the best solution.

Are there other solutions?

thanks

**EDIT**

Here some more specifications about the kind of data I am dealing with.

- The matrices are usually sparse (< 10% or < 25% of cells with non-zero)
- The matrices are symmetric

And what I would need to do is:

- Access for reading only
- Extract rectangular sub-matrices (mostly along the diagonal, but also outside)

Comment: If you can keep the master matrix in memory why are you looking into disk based solutions?

Comment: sorry, I CAN  NOT keep it in memory... I edit the question

Comment: The more information you can give us about your dataset, the better your chances of getting a useful answer. Is your matrix sparse (are most of the entries equal to zero or some other constant)? Does it have other potentially useful properties we should know about (e.g. symmetry)? How you want to index it (e.g. whole rows/columns, rectangular subarrays, random row/column locations etc.)? Is it mostly read-only, or do you frequently need to modify entries?

Comment: You need to look at blaze sub project called dask for out of core computations. Xarray is good example of using dask. Also dask wiki lists alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try PyTables ? It can be very useful for very large matrix. Take a look to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642626/building-a-huge-numpy-array-using-pytables).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking a bit in context; but hdf5 compressed block storage is probably as-efficient as a sparse storage format for these relatively dense matrices you describe. In memory, you can always cast your views to sparse matrices if it pays. That seems like an effective and simple solution; and as far as I know there are no sparse matrix formats which can easily be read partially from disk.