# Linear Regression - What algorithm to use to solve least squares method - inverse or LU or ...?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, least-squares, matrix-inverse

I am working on algorithm to perform linear regression for one or more independent variables.

that is: (if I have `m` real world values and in the case of two independent variables `a` and `b`)

```
C + D*a1 + E* b1 = y1

C + D*a2 + E* b2 = y2

...

C + D*am + E* bm = ym
```

I would like to use the least squares solution to find best fitting straight line.

I will be using the matrix notation
so

[image]

where Beta is the vector  [C, D, E] where these values will be the best fit line.

**Question**
What is the best way to solve this formula? Should I compute the inverse of [image]

or should I use the LU factorization/decmposition of the matrix. What is the performance of each on large amount of data (i.e a big value of `m` , could be in order of 10^8 ...)

**EDIT**

If the answer was to use Cholesky decomposition or QR decomposition, are there any implementation hints/ simple libraries to use.
I am coding in C/ C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your X^TX matrix should have a Cholesky decomposition.  I'd look into this decomposition before LU.  It is faster: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition

Comment: how about computing the inverse? should I avoid that? -- Thanks

Comment: It is generally preferred to avoid matrix inversion. You can run into numerical stability issues, and it can be memory inefficient to store the inverse.  Stick with decomposition methods (they exist for a reason).  Cholesky methods can be found in many packages (gsl etc...)

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your response

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Due to your matrix size, @Saher you might read this post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148052/linear-regression-in-numpy-with-very-large-matrices-how-to-save-memory

Comment: I am using C and will be also using CUDA C on GPU

Comment: tested overall linear regression in python and used Cholesky. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Two straightforward approaches spring to mind for solving a dense overdetermined system Ax=b:

1. Form A^T A x = A b, then Cholesky-factorise A^T A = L L^T, then do two back-solves.  This usually gets you an answer precise to about sqrt(machine epsilon).
2. Compute the QR factorisation A = Q*R, where Q's columns are orthogonal and R is square and upper-triangular, using something like Householder elimination.  Then solve Rx = Q^T b for x by back-substitution.  This usually gets you an answer precise to about machine epsilon --- twice the precision as the Cholesky method, but it takes about twice as long.

For sparse systems, I'd usually prefer the Cholesky method because it takes better advantage of sparsity.