# Build a list of list efficiently in python

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have the following code:

```
neig = []
for _ in xrange(number):
    r = random.randint(0,self._tam-1)
    s = random.randint(0,self._tam-1)
    neig.append([r,s, self.deltaC(r, s)])
```

I am trying to get rid of the for loop using `map`, a generator or something to optimize the build of the list. I've checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6667288/1612432), but in my case I need to give values to the elements.

Would it be possible to use a generator and delay the call to `deltaC`? I think using `map` is not possible because the body of the loop has more than one statement.

Comment: What do you mean "delay the call to `deltaC`? When will you need that value; will you need it for all values in `neig`, and more than once?

Comment: I will be using the value of `deltaC` later in the program. If I have an element of this list of list [1,2,deltaC(1,2)], ¿Could it be evaluate later?. Maybe I misunderstood the concept of generators. If delay the call is not possible, How could I generate this array more efficiently?

Comment: Will you use the value more than once? If not, you could just store `r` and `s` in the list, then call `deltaC(r, s)` where you need that value. What is more important - run time or memory use?

Comment: "Generate this array more efficiently" -- could you clarify what do you mean by more efficient, i.e. what's the problem with the current approach? Is it because ``deltaC`` returns a very huge structure, or that ``number`` is very large, such that it is not feasible to retain the whole list into memory? If this is the case, generators might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using list comprehensions;

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: number = 20

In [3]: tam = 13

In [4]: r = [random.randint(0, tam) for _ in range(number)]

In [5]: s = [random.randint(0, tam) for _ in range(number)]

In [6]: zip(r, s)
Out[6]: [(3, 12), (6, 12), (7, 12), (5, 1), (1, 0), (4, 12), (4, 5), (6, 2), (10, 6), (6, 11), (12, 6), (10, 2), (5, 2), (3, 2), (3, 11), (13, 2), (0, 2), (7, 0), (9, 13), (0, 12)]

In [7]: def deltaC(a, b):
   ...:     return a + b
   ...: 

In [8]: neig = [[p, q, deltaC(p, q)] for p, q in zip(r, s)]

In [9]: neig
Out[9]: [[3, 12, 15], [6, 12, 18], [7, 12, 19], [5, 1, 6], [1, 0, 1], [4, 12, 16], [4, 5, 9], [6, 2, 8], [10, 6, 16], [6, 11, 17], [12, 6, 18], [10, 2, 12], [5, 2, 7], [3, 2, 5], [3, 11, 14], [13, 2, 15], [0, 2, 2], [7, 0, 7], [9, 13, 22], [0, 12, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
neig = ((r, s, self.deltaC(r, s))
        for r, s in ([random.randint(0,self._tam-1),
                      random.randint(0,self._tam-1)]
                     for _ in xrange(number)))
```

provided you only need to iterate over `neig` once.

This will delay the calls to `self.deltaC(r, s)` until they are needed as `neig` is iterated over.

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't remember that I need to sort all items in the list by the value of `deltaC`, so it seems a generator is not going to work here.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I recommend would be to use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
r, s = np.random.randint(0, self._tam, (2, number))
neig = np.concatenate([r, s, self.deltaC(r, s)])
```

This assumes `deltaC` can be written to accept vectors of `r`'s and `s`'s, which should be pretty easy. Note that `np.random.randint` is exclusive on the upper bound (unlike `random.randint`).

Comment: I will try it later, now I have to go, `deltaC` accept two integers representing index in a list. If you have experience with `numpy` I would thank you if you can help me optimizing `deltaC` (http://stackoverflow.com/q/23033416/1612432) Because I have a huge bottleneck there.