# Efficient way to map a function over numpy matrix?

Tags: python, function, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to reproduce an algorithm over image, but failed to achieve the performance of `PIL` on Python.

For simplity, we take *interpolation* as an example.Supposed we have a matrix `Im` of luminance. For any point `(x,y)`, we can compute the interpolation value by `g(x,y)=f(floor(x),floor(y))+f(floor(x)+1,floor(y))+f(floor(x),floor(y)+1)+f(floor(x)+1,floor(y)+1) /4`

Here is part of code. It takes tens of seconds to resize an image, that's inefficient. Also, it's not a element-wise mapping function. It involves with the whole matrix, or more precisely, the neighbour points of each point.

```
im = np.matrix(...) #A 512*512 image
axis = [x/(2047/511.) for x in xrange(2048)]
axis = [(x,y) for x in axis for y in axis] #resize to 2048*2048
im_temp = []
for (x, y) in axis:
    (l, k) = np.floor((x, y)).astype(int)
    a, b = x-l, y-k
    temp = (1-a)*(1-b)*im[l+1,k+1] + a*(1-b)*im[l+2,k+1] + (1-a)*b*im[l+1,k+2] + a*b*im[l+2,k+2]
    im_temp.append(temp)
np.asmatrix(im_temp).reshape((2048,2048)).astype(int)
```

How can we implement this algorithm in a more efficient way instead of 2 `for loop`?

Comment: Share the implementation of `f`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

Comment: Be careful with duplicates; this is a 2d problem.  Flat iteration solutions require reshaping..

Comment: Are `x,y` indices of a 2d array, or coordinates?  Why `floor`?  The `+1` suggests you are looking at neighboring points.   Are you using any Python image packages (beyond numpy)?  Overall this question is underspecified and unclear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740021/numpy-apply-function-to-two-numpy-arrays-and-return-two-numpy-arrays is another recent 'mapping' question that might help.

Comment: The slowness comes from having to evaluate `temp` 2048*2048 times in Python code.  The way to speed that up is to perform the calculations in compiled code, and not iterate or 'map' at all in Python.  `PIL` interfaces with a compiled library, doesn't it?

Comment: @hpaulj, Thanks for your answer. I'm just asking, if we see `temp` as a function w.r.t. a matrix, can we have some efficient way to vectorized the process or speed the performance up.