# Numpy: apply function to two numpy arrays and return two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops, numpy

I have two input numpy arrays with, respectively, latitude and longitude coordinates of a set of points: `lats` and `lons`.

I have inherited a function which converts each `(lat,lon)` pair into an `(E,N)` pair:

```
def convert(lat,lon): #takes two floats as arguments (unit: degrees)
   ...
   computation #Actual function is too long to post
   ...
   return N,E #returns two floats (unit: meters)
```

**My question:** how could I efficiently apply the same function simultaneously to both input numpy arrays?

I was thinking of modifying the function so that it returns a list:

```
return [N,E]
```

in such a way that:

```
rows = int(lat.shape[0]) #lat and lon have the same shape
cols = int(lat.shape[1])
easting=numpy.zeros(shape=(rows,cols))
northing=numpy.zeros(shape=(rows,cols))
for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, cols):
        northing=convert(lon[i][j])[0] #first element of the returned list
        easting=convert(lat[i][j])[1] #second element of the returned list
```

I have not yet tested this, but by looking at it I don't feel very comfortable this will work. Any insights will be much appreciated.

Comment: This will depend on the details of the `convert` function. It might literally already work the way you want it to, or you might have to switch things like `math.sin` to `np.sin`, or it could be essentially impossible to do it efficiently if the code relies on APIs you can't control or replace that take one pair of elements at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's define a trivial conversion

```
def convert(lat, lon):
    return lat*np.pi/180, lon*np.pi/180
```

`frompyfunc` is a useful way of applying 'scalar' function to arrays; We can even have it take in 2 arrays, and return 2 arrays (in a tuple)

```
In [233]: f = np.frompyfunc(convert,2,2)
In [234]: lats=np.linspace(-45,45,5)
In [235]: lons=np.linspace(0,100,5)
In [236]: out = f(lats, lons)
In [237]: out
Out[237]: 
(array([-0.7853981633974483, -0.39269908169872414, 0.0, 0.39269908169872414,
        0.7853981633974483], dtype=object),
 array([0.0, 0.4363323129985824, 0.8726646259971648, 1.3089969389957472,
        1.7453292519943295], dtype=object))
```

One feature is that it returns an object array, while you probably want a float array:

```
In [238]: out[0].astype(float)
Out[238]: array([-0.78539816, -0.39269908,  0.        ,  0.39269908,  0.78539816])
```

Or with unpacking:

```
In [239]: rlat, rlon = f(lats, lons)
In [240]: rlat.astype(float)
Out[240]: array([-0.78539816, -0.39269908,  0.        ,  0.39269908,  0.78539816])
```

`frompyfunc` does iterate through the inputs. In other tests it tends to be 2x faster than more explicit loops.  And in this case, since it returns a tuple you don't have to call it twice to get 2 results.

As written, this `convert` works just as well with arrays as with scalars, so

```
In [241]: convert(lats, lons)
Out[241]: 
(array([-0.78539816, -0.39269908,  0.        ,  0.39269908,  0.78539816]),
 array([ 0.        ,  0.43633231,  0.87266463,  1.30899694,  1.74532925]))
```

which will be much faster than any version that loops in Python.

So for real speed you want `convert` to work directly with arrays.  But if it can't do that, then `frompyfunc` is a modest improvement over do-it-yourself loops.

Another advantage to `frompyfunc` - it applies array broadcasting, as in

```
 f( lats[:,None], lons[None,:])
```