# How to iterate and change all elements of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on a machine learning task and trying to convert all strings in a set of data to floats using `hash()` to do this I need to iterate over all the elements of a numpy array whilst not knowing if it is a 2D 3D or 4D array and then change each element. Is there any way to do this without using nested loops?

Comment: Vectorization is a case-by-case activity. You will have to be very specific if you want a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `numpu.vectorize`, already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43024745/applying-a-function-along-a-numpy-array)

Note:
`The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.`[here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

```py
arr = np.array([['aba', 'baa', 'bbb'],
              ['xxy', 'xyy', 'yyy']])
v_hash = np.vectorize(hash)
v_hash(arr)
```

```
array([[-1538054455328520296, -1528482088733019667, -7962229468338304433],
       [ 5621962119614158870,  1918700875003591346, -3216770211373729154]])
```

Comment: That is a `for` loop under the hood.

Comment: At least it saves from writing nested loops! Anyway if you have the better solution you can provide.

Comment: It's a bad idea. It just hides the slowness under a false veneer of numpyness. I left a comment explaining why I can't. OP did not ask a proper question. You can't vectorize code without knowing what it is