# Return values from a list where difference != 2

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list e.g. `my_list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 14, 16, 18, 22, 28, 30, 32, 41, 43]`

I want a function that will return all values from the list where the difference between that value and previous value is not equal to **2**, e.g. the function will return `[1, 14, 22, 28, 41]` for the above list.  Note that the first value of `my_list` will always appear as the first value of the output.  The input lists are of non-zero length and up to the order of 100's.

So far I have this:

```
def get_output(array):
    start = [array[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(array)-1):
        if (array[i] - array[i-1]) != 2:
            start.append(array[i])

    return start
```

Is there a vectorised solution that would be faster, bearing in mind I will be applying this function to thousands of input arrays?

Comment: why is it returning `1` when there is no element before it?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov that's what I want it to return. First element of output is always first element of input.

Comment: To vectorize your function you need to use numpy. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array) may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid using the inefficient `np.concat`, use `np.ediff1` instead of `np.diff`, which takes a `to_begin` argument to pre-pend to the result:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 14, 16, 18, 22, 28, 30, 32, 41, 43]
>>> arr = np.array(my_list)
>>> np.ediff1d(arr, to_begin=0)
array([0, 2, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 4, 6, 2, 2, 9, 2])
```

So now, using boolean-indexing:

```
>>> arr[np.ediff1d(arr, to_begin=0) != 2]
array([ 1, 14, 22, 28, 41])
```

Comment: or just use boolean indexing: `arr[np.ediff1d(arr, to_begin = 0) != 2]`

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the first element which you can add manually (although it doesn't really make sense as per Azat Ibrakov comment) you can use `np.where`

```
a = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 14, 16, 18, 22, 28, 30, 32, 41, 43])
a[np.where(a[1:] - a[:-1] != 2)[0] + 1]

array([14, 22, 28, 41])
```

Adding first element:

```
[a[0]] + list(a[np.where(a[1:] - a[:-1] != 2)[0] + 1])

[1, 14, 22, 28, 41]
```

Comment: Does a[1:] return a copy object? I mean, how much memory does a[1:] use? As I know, slices return a copy, so it is not memory efficient.

Comment: No copy: slices are just views in numpy.

Comment: Could you prove this (some links)? Because slices of lists is a copy, isn't it?

Comment: try it yourself: modify a slice of a np.array, the original will be modified too.

Comment: Try `a = np.arange(10)`, `b = a[:5]`, `b[0] = 10`, `print(a)`

Comment: Boolean and lists of indices create a copy, slices create views.

Comment: @Julien, thanks! I checked it out and you are right! What about python lists, is there a method to make list slices like numpy slices(views)?

Comment: @DanielF it would take some serious hacking with perhaps `struct` to get the underlying buffer for the `list`. This would rely on python-version-specific implementation details. It would also be entirely unsafe, seeing as Python lists are re-sizable, and the underlying memory would be re-leased and re-allocated somewhere else potentially every time the list re-sizes.

Comment: @DanielF, Thanks, I'm not. I heard about memoryvie, I'll try it.

Comment: And if you want speed and vectorization, numpy is the way, don't waste time hacking python lists for worse results...

Comment: I think I created a monster >.<  Deleting that comment so no one else tries it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) for NumPy arrays and [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) to get the difference between values:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 14, 16, 18, 22, 28, 30, 32, 41, 43]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> my_arr = np.array(my_list)
>>> my_mask = np.ones(my_arr.shape, dtype=bool)  # initial mask
>>> my_mask[1:] = np.diff(my_arr) != 2           # set all elements to False that have a difference of 2
>>> my_arr[my_mask]                              # mask the array
array([ 1, 14, 22, 28, 41])
```

Comment: Might be a little more efficient to initialize `my_mask` with `np.empty(my_arr.shape, dtype=bool)`, `my_mask[0] = True`.  No need to fill with ones from the start

Comment: That's right but the solution already is quite long-ish and the benefit will be quite small. But thank you, I didn't think of that! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 14, 16, 18, 22, 28, 30, 32, 41, 43]
a = np.array(my_list)
output = a[[True] + list(a[1:]-a[:-1] != 2)]
print(output)
```