# numpy vectorize dimension increasing function

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a function that has input: `x.shape==(2,2)`, and outputs `y.shape==(2,2,3)`.

For example:

```
@np.vectorize
def foo(x):
  #This function doesn't work like I want
  return x,x,x

a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
print(foo(a))
#desired output
[[[1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[3 3 3]
  [4 4 4]]]

#actual output
(array([[1, 2],
   [3, 4]]), array([[1, 2],
   [3, 4]]), array([[1, 2],
   [3, 4]]))
```

Or maybe:

```
@np.vectorize
def bar(x):
  #This function doesn't work like I want
  return np.array([x,2*x,5])

a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
print(bar(a))
#desired output
[[[1 2 5]
  [2 4 5]]

 [[3 6 5]
  [4 8 5]]]
```

Note that `foo` is just an example.  I want a way to `map` over a numpy array (which is what vectorize is supposed to do), but have that `map` take a 0d object and shove a 1d object in its place.  It also seems to me that the dimensions here are arbitrary, as one might wish to take a function that takes a 1d object and returns a 3d object, vectorize it, call it on a 5d object, and get back a 7d object.... However, my specific use case only requires vectorizing a 0d to 1d function, and mapping it appropriately over a 2d array.

Comment: Can you elaborate how this 1d-objects is created? What does it depend on?

Comment: via the function `foo`.  I can include more examples of a function that takes a 0d argument and returns a 1d object....

Comment: Is the question yet clear?  Why is this a bad question?  Is mapping over numpy arrays not something that other people want to do?

Comment: Well, you might as well write your own loop. `np.vectorize` isn't really performant anyway, so if it's not doing what you want just do the iteration yourself.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is known to me, however, looping isn't very numpythonic :), and anyhow, I'm not tied specifically to the `vectorize` function.  I just want a way to perform the mapping operation that I've described.

Comment: `np.vectorize`, in its default mode, passes scalar elements from the arguments to your function.  There is a way of specifying dimensions, but it's more complicated. Either way it's at best a convenience function, not a way of speeding up your code.

Comment: If you are just worried about 'numpythonic' just hide your loops in a function call :)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array). There is no standard way to map over a numpy array, even in the simple case of a single dimension. Usually, the best answer is to translate into vectorized ufuncs. You can always write your own, using C or Cython. Also, there is the JITed route using `numba`. I've found it is a good tool for writing more complex operations in a space-efficient way that also maintains speed without the need to delve into C-extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help, in your question, to show both the actual result and your desired result.  As written that isn't very clear.

```
In [79]: foo(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]))
Out[79]: 
(array([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]), array([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]), array([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]))
```

As indicated in the `vectorize` docs, this has returned a tuple of arrays, corresponding to the tuple of values that your function returned.

Your `bar` returns an array, where as `vectorize` expected it to return a scalar (or single value):

```
In [82]: bar(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]))
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

`vectorize` takes an `otypes` parameter that sometimes helps.  For example if I say that `bar` (without the wrapper) returns an object, I get:

```
In [84]: f=np.vectorize(bar, otypes=[object])

In [85]: f(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]))
Out[85]: 
array([[array([1, 2, 5]), array([2, 4, 5])],
       [array([3, 6, 5]), array([4, 8, 5])]], dtype=object)
```

A (2,2) array of (3,) arrays.  The `(2,2)` shape matches the shape of the input.

`vectorize` has a relatively new parameter, `signature`

```
In [90]: f=np.vectorize(bar, signature='()->(n)')

In [91]: f(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]))
Out[91]: 
array([[[1, 2, 5],
        [2, 4, 5]],

       [[3, 6, 5],
        [4, 8, 5]]])
In [92]: _.shape
Out[92]: (2, 2, 3)
```

I haven't used this much, so am still getting a feel for how it works.  When I've tested it, it is slower than the original scalar version of `vectorize`.  Neither offers any speed advantage of explicit loops.  However `vectorize` does help when 'broadcasting', allowing you to use a variety of input shapes.  That's even more useful when your function takes several inputs, not just one as in this case.

```
In [94]: f(np.array([1,2]))
Out[94]: 
array([[1, 2, 5],
       [2, 4, 5]])

In [95]: f(np.array(3))
Out[95]: array([3, 6, 5])
```

---

For best speed, you want to use existing numpy whole-array functions where possible.  For example your `foo` case can be done with:

```
In [97]: np.repeat(a[:,:,None],3, axis=2)
Out[97]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]]])
```

`np.stack([a]*3, axis=2)` also works.

And your `bar` desired result:

```
In [100]: np.stack([a, 2*a, np.full(a.shape, 5)], axis=2)
Out[100]: 
array([[[1, 2, 5],
        [2, 4, 5]],

       [[3, 6, 5],
        [4, 8, 5]]])
```

`2*a` takes advantage of the whole-array multiplication.  That's true 'numpy-onic' thinking.

Comment: I timeit'd this last thing, `np.stack`..., the solution in my answer takes 5 times as long.

Answer (score 2):

Just repeating the value into another dimension is quite simple:

```
import numpy as np

x = a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
y = np.repeat(x[:,:,np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
print y.shape
print y


(2L, 2L, 3L)
[[[1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[3 3 3]
  [4 4 4]]]
```

Comment: I do not need to simply repeat the value into another dimension, that was merely an example...

Comment: I'll think of it as soon as I find the time. It's an interesting problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for the "f R0 -> R1 mapped over a nd array giving a (n+1)d one"

```
def foo(x):
  return np.concatenate((x,x))
np.apply_along_axis(foo,2,x.reshape(list(x.shape)+[1]))
```

doesn't generalize all that well, though

Comment: This apply function just hides a loop.

Comment: "hides a loop": hides a python loop, or hides a machine language loop?  AFAIK, a map operation essentially must boil down to "1) operator, memory increment, check for end, if not, goto 1)"

Comment: Click on the [source] link on the documentation page, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/lib/shape_base.py#L23-L167.  Note the use of `ndindex` and the `for ind in inds:` loop.

Comment: numpy isn't numpythonic.  :)