# Mapping function across numpy matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Is there a way to map a function to every value in a numpy array easily? I've done it before by splitting it into lists, using list comprehension and remaking the matrix but it seems there must be an easier way.

Comment: `vectorize` is easy to use - usually.  But beware there have been a lot of questions about why doesn't it work - or why doesn't work faster.

Comment: If you wan't to achieve significant speedups have a look at http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/jit-compilation.html#vectorized-functions-ufuncs-and-dufuncs

If you are looping on an array about a speedup of a factor of 100 can usually be observed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`np.vectorize()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def myfunc(a, b):
...     if a > b:
...             return a - b
...     else:
...             return a + b
...
>>> vfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc)
>>> vfunc(np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]),2)
array([[3, 4, 1],
       [3, 4, 1]])
```

There are some cases where you do not need `np.vectorize()`, and you simply able to call the function using an `np.array()` as a parameter, like so:

```
>>> def add_one(x):
...     return x + 1
...
>>> add_one(np.array([1,2,3,4]))
array([2, 3, 4, 5])
>>>
```

Much more discussion on performance and usage can be found here:

[Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

Comment: No need for `vectorize()`, just call `f(x)`, it's automatic.

Comment: @liliscent Updated my answer to show a case where `vectorize` is required.

Comment: @Owen683 If this answered your question, please accept as an accepted answer.

Comment: @chrisz It makes sense since I find OP is asking "an easy way", not "performant way". Just as stated in your linked question, `vectorize()` provides no performance gain. Upvoted..