# Convert numpy array of colour images to a numpy array of gray scale images

Tags: python, numpy

How do I convert an array of two colour images to an **array** of two gray scale images using the `to_grayscale` (from this [site](http://www.degeneratestate.org/posts/2016/Oct/23/image-processing-with-numpy/)) function below.

**Important:** I don't want image files, I want the array `image_g` defined below.

First create the function and sample images:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'
np.random.seed(0)

def to_grayscale(im):
    tile = np.tile(np.c_[0.333, 0.333, 0.333], reps=(im.shape[0],im.shape[1],1))
    return np.sum(tile * im, axis=2)

images = np.random.randint(0, 255, 24).reshape(2, 2, 2, 3)
images.shape

out> (2, 2, 2, 3)
```

Have a look at the first image:

```
plt.imshow(images[1])
```

[image]

View as gray scale:

```
plt.imshow(to_grayscale(images[1]))
```

[image]

How do I convert `images` to an array of gray scale images `image_g`?  I'd like to do something like this:

```
image_g = np.somefunction(to_grayscale, images)
images_g.shape

out> (2, 2, 2)
```

where `somefunction` is a placeholder for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PIL`

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image.png').convert('LA')
img.save('greyscale.png')
```

Comment: This does not answer the question because it does not result in array `image_g`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the fastest or most elegant way to do this in general, based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

```
images_g = np.array([to_grayscale(images[i]) for i in range(images.shape[0])])
```