# convert 1-D array to 2-D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

How can I create a 2-d array from 1-d array in python?

```
Example :

     i/p 1-D array : [3,4,6]

Result :

     o/p 2-D array : [[3,], [4,], [6,]]
```

Or lets say a dataframe column with `values = [3,4,6]` as the 2-d above mentioned array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use reshape to deal with numpy arrays. ([Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html))

Ex:

```
a = [1,2,3]
#reshaping a into 1 column and 3 rows
b = np.reshape(a,(3,1))

print(b)
```

to be more general you can just use the length of a as argument for the number of rows:

```
b = np.reshape(a,(len(a),1))
```

Note: As far as I know (someone correct me if I'm wrong), using numpy to deal with numpy arrays is faster. In other cases I suppose the list comprehension example would be the faster option.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an array for each element:

```python
array = [3,4,6]
array2 = [[x] for x in array]
print(array2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7GoKLFSwVYh2ljHRMcslgvMNwIJRFfEKqTlFylUKGTmKYCFY7kKijLzSjQgajT//wcA)

Or use `map()`:

```python
array = [3,4,6]
array2 = list(map(lambda x: [x], array))
print(array2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7GoKLFSwVYh2ljHRMcslgvMNwIK5GQWl2jkJhZo5CTmJqUkKlRYKURXxOoogBVoanIVFGXmlWhAlGv@/w8A)

Comment: Thanks.. that worked for list.. what about if its a 1-D numpy array or a dataframe column

Comment: @AIMCognitiveGurgaonBigData read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array#35215329