# How to draw from two different gaussians conditionally on some Bernoulli distribution?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have two gaussian distributions (I'm using `multivariate_normal`) and I'd like to draw from them with probability of `p` for the first gaussian and `1-p` for the other one. I'd like to make `n` draws.

Is it possible to do that without a `for` loop? (for efficiency purposes)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to perform this operation without a loop. Try:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

sample_size = 100
p = 0.25

# Flip a coin with P(HEADS) = p to determine which distribution to draw from
indicators = stats.bernoulli.rvs(p, size=sample_size)

# Draw from N(0, 1) w/ probability p and N(-1, 1) w/ probability (1-p)
draws = (indicators == 1) * np.random.normal(0, 1, size=sample_size) + \
    (indicators == 0) * np.random.normal(-1, 1, size=sample_size)
```

You can accomplish the same thing using [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) [(*caveat emptor*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array):

```
def draw(x):
  if x == 0:
     return np.random.normal(-1, 1)
  elif x == 1:
     return np.random.normal(0, 1)

draw_vec = np.vectorize(draw)    
draws = draw_vec(indicators)
```

If you need to extend the solution to a mixture of more than 2 distributions, you can use [`np.random.multinomial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html) to assign samples to distributions and add additional cases to the `if/else` in `draw`.

Comment: but there's a slight problem, is it also possible to label each sample accordingly?

Comment: The labels corresponding to which distribution a sample is drawn from are the entries in the `indicators` array. More explicitly put, you might try: `draws_with_labels = zip(draws, indicators)`.

Comment: Did you notice that `draws` contains just two distinct values?  I don't think that is the desired behavior.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, I've fixed the issue you spotted and included another example which accomplishes the desired task.