# How to plot scalar functions of matrices in matplotlib involving matrix_power?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I have the following code to plot scalar `x` vs scalar `f(x)` where there is some matrix multiplication inside the function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.linalg import matrix_power
P=np.array([\
 [0,0,0.5,0,0.5],\
 [0,0,1,0,0], \
 [.25,.25,0,.25,.25], \
 [0,0,.5,0,.5], \
 [0,0,0,0,1], \
 ])
t=np.array([0,1,0,0,0])
ones=np.array([1,1,1,1,0])

def f(x):
    return t.dot(matrix_power(P,x)).dot(ones)
x=np.arange(1,20)
plt.plot(x, f(x))
```

Now, the function by itself works fine.

```
>>> f(1)
1.0
>>> f(2)
0.75
```

But the plotting raises the error `exponent must be an integer`.

To put it another way, how do I evaluate this function upon an array? e.g.

`f(np.array([1,2]))`

I tried replacing the plot line with 
`plt.plot(x, map(f,x))`

But this didn't help.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't "omit something for simplicity"!

Comment: ok, I've just put them back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: P=np.array([\ 
   ...:  [0,0,0.5,0,0.5],\ 
   ...:  [0,0,1,0,0], \ 
   ...:  [.25,.25,0,.25,.25], \ 
   ...:  [0,0,.5,0,.5], \ 
   ...:  [0,0,0,0,1], \ 
   ...:  ])                                                                     
In [2]:                                                                         
In [2]: P                                                                       
Out[2]: 
array([[0.  , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.5 ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.25, 0.25, 0.  , 0.25, 0.25],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.5 ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  ]])

In [4]: np.linalg.matrix_power(P,3)                                             
Out[4]: 
array([[0.   , 0.   , 0.25 , 0.   , 0.75 ],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.5  , 0.   , 0.5  ],
       [0.125, 0.125, 0.   , 0.125, 0.625],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.25 , 0.   , 0.75 ],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 1.   ]])

In [5]: np.linalg.matrix_power(P,np.arange(0,4))                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
TypeError: exponent must be an integer
```

So just give it the integer that it wants:

```
In [10]: [f(i) for i in range(4)]                                               
Out[10]: [1.0, 1.0, 0.75, 0.5]

pylab.plot(np.arange(25), [f(i) for i in np.arange(25)])
```

---

From the `matrix_power` code:

```
a = asanyarray(a)
_assertRankAtLeast2(a)
_assertNdSquareness(a)

try:
    n = operator.index(n)
except TypeError:
    raise TypeError("exponent must be an integer")
....
```

Here's what it does for `n=3`:

```
In [5]: x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)                                           
In [6]: np.linalg.matrix_power(x,3)                                             
Out[6]: 
array([[ 180,  234,  288],
       [ 558,  720,  882],
       [ 936, 1206, 1476]])
In [7]: x@x@x                                                                   
Out[7]: 
array([[ 180,  234,  288],
       [ 558,  720,  882],
       [ 936, 1206, 1476]])
```

You could define a `matrix_power` function that accepts an array of powers:

```
def matrix_power(P,x):
    return np.array([np.linalg.matrix_power(P,i) for i in x])
```

With this `matrix_power(P,np.arange(25))` would produce a (25,5,5) array.  And your `f(x)` actually does work with that, returning a (25,) shape array.  But I wonder, was that just fortuitous, or was it intentional?  Did you write `f` with a 3d power array in mind?

```
t.dot(matrix_power(P,x)).dot(ones)
```

Comment: can you show how to use this in the `plt.plot` function, as a function, rather than a list of values? I think that is what I really need.

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear: Can you use a function, **not** a comprehension list of values?  In other words, I want the paradigm of 
`x=np.arange(25)\

plt.plot(x,np.sin(x))`?  
ie. `sin(x)` seems to work without requiring me to make a list comprehension.My function doesn't.  I want to make my function work as simply as the sin(x) paradigm.  Your answer seems 'over-specified' since it requires the range to be specified twice

Comment: And the real problem "exponent must be an integer" remains unexplained.

Comment: @Tim ` np.array` returns an array, not an int (seemingly `matrix_power` can't handle arrays). Also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

Comment: `np.linalg.matrix_power(x,3)` does `x@x@x`, that is, repeated matrix products.  That only makes sense for an integer value.  Right at the start it checks that `n` is a scalar integer.  It is not coded to work with a list or array of powers.  You get to do that, as I illustrated.

Comment: 'seemingly `matrix_power` can't handle arrays' : @user8408080 is the crux for me.  I expected that numpy's functions always know how to handle arrays.  But only some, apparently.

Comment: `matrix_power` does know how to handle an array - the first argument.  But the docs are quite explicit - the second argument is an integer.