# How to get a square root to a list

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to know if there is any way to get a square root to a list?

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

```
import math
import numpy as np 

secuencia_1=5
secuencia_2=[7, 2, 4, 8, -1, -6, 5, -3]

ar=np.array(secuencia_2)

r=np.prod((math.sqrt(secuencia_1*secuencia_1)))

g=((ar*ar))      
d=(math.sqrt(ar*ar))    

print(d)
```

Comment: *"condition... square root of lists"* Something's wrong or I'm not getting it right!?

Comment: Could you format your code to make it easier to read? Just edit your question, highlight all the code and press the `{}` button

Comment: apologies I'm just starting in this forum

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to iterate a function (in this case square root) on a list.

Would recommend using map(function,list)

e.g.

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
sqr_x = map(math.sqrt,x)
```

Or if you want to stick with numpy:

See numpy vectorize : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

and/or any of the other answers here : [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're asking:
"I want to make a condition in python that uses a square root."

Going off of that, I would point you to the Math library.

[Math.sqrt](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/math.html#math.sqrt)