# RegEx matching for removing a sequence of variable length in a number

Tags: python, regex, numpy

I have a numpy array of integers that look like this X000Y000. X and Y can be of length 1, 2, or 3 and might contain 0s. I want to transform every element in the array to just X. I feel like a regex could be used for this but cannot figure out a good one to use, or how to apply that to a whole array.

Example: 14000010000 should become 140.

Comment: How can you tell it's 140 and not 14?

Comment: Because there are exactly three 0s after X and three 0s after Y that should be deleted.

Comment: Why  doesn't it become `14010`?

Comment: `X` is `140` and `Y` is `10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `X` and `Y` can't begin with `0`. `[1-9]\d{0,2}` matches a number from 1 to 3 digits that doesn't begin with `0`.

So the regexp to extract `X` and `Y` should be:

```
^([1-9]\d{0,2})000([1-9]\d{0,2})000$
```

Then you can use `re.sub()` to remove the zeroes between `X` and `Y`.

```
regex = re.compile(r'^([1-9]\d{0,2})000([1-9]\d{0,2})000$');
i = 14000010000
istr = str(i)
new_i = int(regex.sub(r'\1\2', istr)
```

You can map this over your numpy array

```
regex = re.compile(r'^([1-9]\d{0,2})000([1-9]\d{0,2})000$');
new_array = np.fromiter((int(regex.sub(r'\1\2', str(x)) for x in array), array.dtype)
```

See [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array) for various ways of mapping a function over a numpy array.

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @user3483203 Yes, I misread the answer at the question I linked to above.