# save time with lambda function + map with 2D array

Tags: python, for-loop, lambda

I was convinced to save computation time in using lambda function, but it's not that clear. look at this example:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def f_with_lambda():
    a = np.array(range(5))
    b = np.array(range(5))
    A,B = np.meshgrid(a,b)

    rst = list(map(lambda x,y : x+y , A, B))

    return np.array(rst)

def f_with_for():
    a = range(5)
    b = np.array(range(5))

    rst = [b+x for x in a]

    return np.array(rst)

lambda_rst = f_with_lambda()
for_rst = f_with_for()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(timeit.timeit("f_with_lambda()",setup = "from __main__ import f_with_lambda",number = 10000))
    print(timeit.timeit("f_with_for()",setup = "from __main__ import f_with_for",number = 10000))
```

result is simple:
-lambda function result with time it is 0.3514268280014221 s
- with for loop : 0.10633227700236603 s

**How do I write my lambda function to be competitive ?** I noticed the list function to get results from de map object is not good in time. Any other way to proceed ? the mesgrid function is certainly not the best as well...

every tip is welcome!

Comment: Have you tried with bigger values for a and b ?

Comment: yes, for example with 150 instead of 5: 2.696938256998692s vs 
1.9488381640003354s

Comment: Where have you read that with `lambda` it should be faster? I understand the use of `map`. But using `lambda` should not make it faster. Isn't better to define a function like `add(a,b)` and then pass that to `map()`?

Comment: Look at my edit, it becomes faster and competitive without the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory allocation is taking time (it should call an OS procedure, it might be delayed).
In the lambda version, you allocated `a`, `b`, `meshgrid`, `rst` (list and array versions) + the `return` array.
In the for version, you allocated `b` and `rst` + the `return` array. `a` is a generator so it takes no time to create and load it in memory.

This is why your function using lambda is slower.

Plus, don't use `list` to handle result of np-array operations to cast it back to np-array.
Just by removing the `list()` it become faster (from 0.9 to 0.4).

```
def f_with_lambda():
    a = np.array(range(SIZE))
    b = np.array(range(SIZE))
    A,B = np.meshgrid(a,b)

    rst = map(lambda x,y : x+y , A, B)

    return np.array(rst)
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46470401/9453926 for speed comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the remark about the list:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def f_with_lambda():
    A,B = np.meshgrid(range(150),range(150))
    return np.array(map(lambda x,y : x+y , A, B))


def f_with_for():
    return np.array([np.array(range(150))+x for x in range(150)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(timeit.timeit("f_with_lambda()",setup = "from __main__ import f_with_lambda",number = 10000))
    print(timeit.timeit("f_with_for()",setup = "from __main__ import f_with_for",number = 10000))
```

it is changing a lot of things. This time (lambda vs for)

for 5:
0.30227499100146815 vs 0.2510572589999356 (quite similar)

for 150:
0.6687559890015109 vs 20.31807473200024 ( :) :) :) ) !! great job! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I compacted the code:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def f_with_lambda():
    A,B = np.meshgrid(range(150),range(150))
    return np.array(list(map(lambda x,y : x+y , A, B)))


def f_with_for():
    return np.array([np.array(range(150))+x for x in range(150)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(timeit.timeit("f_with_lambda()",setup = "from __main__ import f_with_lambda",number = 10000))
    print(timeit.timeit("f_with_for()",setup = "from __main__ import f_with_for",number = 10000))
```

This time, for a 5x5, the result is

Lambda vs for

0.38113487999726203 vs 0.24913009200099623

and with 150 it's better:

2.680842614001449 vs 20.176408246999927

But I found no way to integrate the mesgrid inside the lambda function. and the list conversion before the array is sad as well.

Comment: I havent see your last part concerning the list. I try.

Comment: You are still using a list [] and converting it to array. Forget about lists. Use numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

I took time to integrate the last remark from politinsa:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def f_with_lambda():
    A,B = np.meshgrid(range(150),range(150))
    return np.array(list(map(lambda x,y : x+y , A, B)))


def f_with_for():
    return np.array([np.array(range(150))+x for x in range(150)])

def f_with_lambda_nolist():
    A,B = np.meshgrid(range(150),range(150))
    return np.array(map(lambda x,y : x+y , A, B))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(timeit.timeit("f_with_lambda()",setup = "from __main__ import f_with_lambda",number = 10000))
    print(timeit.timeit("f_with_for()",setup = "from __main__ import f_with_for",number = 10000))
    print(timeit.timeit("f_with_lambda_nolist()",setup = "from __main__ import f_with_lambda_nolist",number = 10000))
```

results are:
2.4421722999977646 s
18.75847979998798 s
0.6800016999914078 s -> list conversion has (as explained) a real impact on memory allocation