# mapping custom function over multidimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a multidimensional array

```
example =[[[1,1,2,2],[1,1,2,2]],[[1,1,3,3],[1,1,4,4]]]
```

for a simple call for an index a function used gives decent output

```
def calculate_sum(arr1,arr2):
    s = arr1[0]+arr2[0]+arr1[1]+arr2[3]
    return s

s = calculate_sum(example[1][0],example[1][1])
s
```

I can easily use for loop to iterate over example but want to know how to modify the function to vectorize over the array " example " to speed up the code

I have refered to similar threads but none deal with multidimensional arrays mapping properly

[Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

Comment: You mention you want to **speed up the code** by using numpy.vectorize. But vecotrize function is not meant to be used for performance, but for convenience. Here's a extract from the documentation "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Comment: Is there no method of vectorizing that has better speed than for loop ? I didnt know this was the case