# How to map a function over numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, lambda

I would like to be able to apply a generic function on either scalars numpy 1-D arrays, o numpy 2-D arrays.
The example in point is

```
def stress2d_lefm_cyl(KI, r, qdeg) :
    """Compute stresses in Mode I around a 2D crack, according to LEFM
    q should be input in degrees"""
    sfactor = KI / sqrt(2*pi*r)
    q = radians(qdeg)
    q12 = q/2;        q32 = 3*q/2;
    sq12 = sin(q12);  cq12 = cos(q12);
    sq32 = sin(q32);  cq32 = cos(q32);
    af11 = cq12 * (1 - sq12*sq32);  af22 = cq12 * (1 + sq12*sq32);
    af12 = cq12 * sq12 * cq32
    return sfactor * np.array([af11, af22, af12])

def stress2d_lefm_rect(KI, x, y) :
    """Compute stresses in Mode I around a 2D crack, according to LEFM
    """
    r = sqrt(x**2+y**2)   <-- Error line
    q = atan2(y, x)
    return stress2d_lefm_cyl(KI, r, degrees(q))

delta = 0.5
x = np.arange(-10.0, 10.01, delta)
y = np.arange(0.0, 10.01, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
KI = 1
# I want to pass a scalar KI, and either scalar, 1D, or 2D arrays for X,Y (of the same shape, of course)
Z = stress2d_lefm_rect(KI, X, Y)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

(I mean to use this for a contour plot).
If I now change to

```
def stress2d_lefm_rect(KI, x, y) :
    """Compute stresses in Mode I around a 2D crack, according to LEFM
    """
    r = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2   <-- Now this works
    q = lambda x,y: atan2(y, x)   <-- Error line
    return stress2d_lefm_cyl(KI, r(x,y), degrees(q(x,y)))
Z = stress2d_lefm_rect(KI, X, Y)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

which boils down to

```
x = np.array([1.0, 2, 3, 4, 5])
h = lambda x,y: atan2(y,x)  <-- Error
print(h(0,1))   <-- Works
print(h(x, x))  <-- Error

1.5707963267948966

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

A "similar" question was posted, [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array/35216364)
The differences are:
1. I have to (or possibly more) arguments (`x`,`y`), which should have the same shape.
2. I am combining also with a scalar argument (`KI`).
3. `atan2` seems to be less "tolerant" than `**2`. I mean to work with a generic function.
4. I am chaining two functions.

**Can this be worked out?**
Perhaps point 2 can be overcome by multiplying the result somewhere else.

Comment: `math.tan` only works with scalar values.  `np.tan` works with array inputs.

Comment: You really just need to use numpy functions and it will all work out as expected. Maybe use this? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use numpy to apply your function to every element of an array.

Ex :

```
import numpy as np
np.sqrt(np.square(x) + np.square(y))
```

Comment: Similarly, you can use `np.arctan2(y,x)` but x and y should have the same shape, which is not your case.

Comment: As a side note, r is equal to eucildean distance in your case, so you can use : 

```from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean;```

```euclidean(x,y)```

Comment: Yes, I had to use np.arctan2. My arrays were ok, both the same shape.

Comment: Note: I didn't need `np.square`, `**2` worked fine.