# Using a numpy array in if condition cause problems, how to fix it?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to test every single element of "z", with the "if else" condition and return desired equation. My implementation is resulting with an error. I tried "z.all" and "z.any" functions but these two are converting "z" to a boolean array. I do not want z as boolean array. How can I do this, while z remain as a numpy array?

z is a **numpy array** and its shape is **(10610, ))**

```
    def function(z):
        alpha = 1
        if (z < 0):
            return -alpha * z
        elif (0 <= z <= 1):
            return (3 * z ** 3) - (4 * z ** 2) + (2 * z)
        else:
            return z
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the methods `any` and `all` are not acceptable?

Comment: @Brian Z is storing numbers to use later. I would like to feed each element into if-else individually. When I use `any` or `all` it turns out each elements to a  '1' or '0'. Isn't it?

Comment: _is resulting with an error_ What error? **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for the two conditions:

```
np.where(
    z < 0,
    -alpha * z,
    np.where(
        z <= 1,
        (3 * z ** 3) - (4 * z ** 2) + (2 * z),
        z))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to apply your function to all elements in the array z right? If so you might want to look into numpys [vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) function.

For your code:

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(function)
z = vfunc(z)
```

If speed and efficiency are important you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array) other answer where different methods are compared.

Answer (score 0):

Using [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
def function(z):
    alpha = 1

    m = (z < 0)
    z[m] = -alpha * z[m]

    m = ((z >= 0) & (z <= 1))
    z[m] = (3 * z[m] ** 3) - (4 * z[m] ** 2) + (2 * z[m])

    return z
```