# Is my Python/Cython iteration benchmark representative?

Tags: python, iteration, cython, benchmarking, typed-memory-views

I want to iterate through a large data structure in a Python program and perform a task for each element. For simplicity, let's say the elements are integers and the task is just an incrementation. In the end, the last incremented element is returned as (dummy) result. In search of the best structure/method to do this I compared timings in pure Python and Cython for these structures (I could not find a direct comparison of them elsewhere):

- Python list
- NumPy array / typed memory view
- Cython extension type with underlying C++ vector

The iterations I timed are:

- Python foreach in list iteration (it_list)
- Cython list iteration with explicit element access (cit_list)
- Python foreach in array iteration (it_nparray)
- Python NumPy vectorised operation (vec_nparray)
- Cython memory view iteration with explicit element access (cit_memview)
- Python foreach in underlying vector iteration (it_pyvector)
- Python foreach in underlying vector iteration via __iter__ (it_pyvector_iterator)
- Cython vector iteration with explicit element access (cit_pyvector)
- Cython vector iteration via vector.iterator (cit_pyvector_iterator)

I am concluding from this (timings are below):

- plain Python iteration over the NumPy array is extremely slow (about 10 times slower than the Python list iteration) -> not a good idea
- Python iteration over the wrapped C++ vector is slow, too (about 1.5 times slower than the Python list iteration) -> not a good idea
- Cython iteration over the wrapped C++ vector is the fastest option, approximately equal to the C contiguous memory view
- The iteration over the vector using explicit element access is slightly faster than using an iterator -> why bother to use an iterator?
- The memory view approach has comparably larger overhead than the extension type approach

My question is now: Are my numbers reliable (did I do something wrong or miss anything here)? Is this in line with your experience with real-world examples? Is there anything else I could do to improve the iteration? Below the code that I used and the timings. I am using this in a Jupyter notebook by the way. Suggestions and comments are highly appreciated!

Relative timings (minimum value 1.000), for different data structure sizes n:

```
================================================================================
Timings for n = 1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cit_pyvector_iterator:   1.000
             cit_pyvector:   1.005
                 cit_list:   1.023
                  it_list:   3.064
              it_pyvector:   4.230
     it_pyvector_iterator:   4.937
              cit_memview:   8.196
              vec_nparray:  20.187
               it_nparray:  25.310
================================================================================ 

================================================================================
Timings for n = 1000:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cit_pyvector_iterator:   1.000
             cit_pyvector:   1.001
              cit_memview:   2.453
              vec_nparray:   5.845
                 cit_list:   9.944
                  it_list: 137.694
              it_pyvector: 199.702
     it_pyvector_iterator: 218.699
               it_nparray: 1516.080
================================================================================ 

================================================================================
Timings for n = 1000000:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             cit_pyvector:   1.000
              cit_memview:   1.056
    cit_pyvector_iterator:   1.197
              vec_nparray:   2.516
                 cit_list:   7.089
                  it_list:  87.099
     it_pyvector_iterator: 143.232
              it_pyvector: 162.374
               it_nparray: 897.602
================================================================================ 

================================================================================
Timings for n = 10000000:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             cit_pyvector:   1.000
              cit_memview:   1.004
    cit_pyvector_iterator:   1.060
              vec_nparray:   2.721
                 cit_list:   7.714
                  it_list:  88.792
     it_pyvector_iterator: 130.116
              it_pyvector: 149.497
               it_nparray: 872.798
================================================================================
```

Cython code:

```py
%%cython --annotate

# distutils: language = c++
# cython: boundscheck = False
# cython: wraparound = False

from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref, preincrement as princ


# Extension type wrapping a vector
cdef class pyvector:
    cdef vector[long] _data

    cpdef void push_back(self, long x):
        self._data.push_back(x)

    def __iter__(self):
        cdef size_t i, n = self._data.size()

        for i in range(n):
            yield self._data[i]

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data


# Cython iteration over Python list      
cpdef long cit_list(list l):
    cdef:
        long j, ii
        size_t i, n = len(l)

    for i in range(n):
        ii = l[i]
        j = ii + 1  
    return j


# Cython iteration over NumPy array
cpdef long cit_memview(long[::1] v) nogil:
    cdef:
        size_t i, n = v.shape[0]
        long j

    for i in range(n):
        j = v[i] + 1   
    return j


# Iterate over pyvector
cpdef long cit_pyvector(pyvector v) nogil:
    cdef:
        size_t i, n = v._data.size()
        long j

    for i in range(n):
        j = v._data[i] + 1
    return j    


cpdef long cit_pyvector_iterator(pyvector v) nogil:
    cdef:
        vector[long].iterator it = v._data.begin()
        long j

    while it != v._data.end():
        j = deref(it) + 1
        princ(it)
    return j
```

Python code:

```py
# Python iteration over Python list
def it_list(l):
    for i in l:
        j = i + 1    
    return j


# Python iteration over NumPy array
def it_nparray(a):
    for i in a:
        j = i + 1    
    return j


# Vectorised NumPy operation
def vec_nparray(a):
    a + 1
    return a[-1]


# Python iteration over C++ vector extension type
def it_pyvector_iterator(v):
    for i in v:
        j = i + 1
    return j


def it_pyvector(v):
    for i in v.data:
        j = i + 1
    return j
```

And for the benchmark:

```py
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter


def bm(sizes):
    """Call functions with data structures of varying length"""

    Timings = {}
    for n in sizes:
        Timings[n] = {}

        # Python list
        list_ = list(range(n))

        # NumPy array
        a = np.arange(n, dtype=np.int64)

        # C++ vector extension type
        pyv = pyvector()
        for i in range(n):
            pyv.push_back(i)


        calls = [
            (it_list, list_),
            (cit_list, list_),
            (it_nparray, a),
            (vec_nparray, a),
            (cit_memview, a),
            (it_pyvector, pyv),
            (it_pyvector_iterator, pyv),
            (cit_pyvector, pyv),
            (cit_pyvector_iterator, pyv),
        ]

        for fxn, arg in calls:
            Timings[n][fxn.__name__] = %timeit -o fxn(arg)

    return Timings


def ratios(timings, base=None):
    """Show relative performance of runs based on `timings` dict"""

    if base is not None:
        base = timings[base].average
    else:
        base = min(x.average for x in timings.values())

    return sorted([
        (k, v.average / base)
        for k, v in timings.items()
        ], key=itemgetter(1))


Timings = {}
sizes = [1, 1000, 1000000, 10000000]
Timings.update(bm(sizes))
for s in sizes:
    print("=" * 80)
    print(f"Timings for n = {s}:")
    print("-" * 80)
    for x in ratios(Timings[s]):
        print(f"{x[0]:>25}: {x[1]:7.3f}")
    print("=" * 80, "\n")
```

Comment: A good ahead-of-time compiler could in theory optimize those functions to just return the last element + 1 without actually iterating.  Summing or XORing all the array elements might be more realistic.  It doesn't look like that's a problem with your Cython or CPython tests, but IDK if any other unused-result optimizations are happening.   (You would want to keep the numbers small (like under 2^30) so Python can use its single-chunk fast path instead of full BigInteger handling, so you'd want to keep each element small if you were changing your test.)

Comment: Posted as a comment because I can't justify adding enough to make it an answer: yes this looks basically right. Obviously in a real program take into account the source of your data - there's probably little point in converting Python arrays to c++ vectors just for a slightly faster loop

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54312134/5769463

Comment: @PeterCordes, I don't think he wants that kind of optimization (which Python doesn't attempt).  The fact that `j = i + 1` doesn't accumulate values during the iteration is an oversight, and reduces the value of the time tests.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's a good point with the compiler. I realised that when I do not return a value explicitly from the functions, the iterations in the "nogil" cdef functions just seem to be skipped, making them millions of times faster than the Python variants. This is obviously not what I wanted to test. Also interesting to keep in mind that the integers should be small to make the Python/Cython comparison fair.

Comment: @DavidW Luckily I am relatively free to choose the structure at the moment, but this is definitely something to consider. If there is nothing wrong with the iterations themselves, I am totally happy with that right now.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, using the increment in the loop was just an attempt to decouple the logic happening for each element from the iteration (except for element access) as much as possible. I will test the different methods with something more meaningful. The actual background is finding connected components in a linear sparse graph, so: looping over vertices, checking a condition, starting a breadth-first-search.