# Row-wise replacement of numpy array with values of another numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have `0`s and `1`s store in a 3-dimensional numpy array:

```
g = np.array([[[0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]], [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]]])
# array([
#     [[0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]],
#     [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]]])
```

and I'd like to replace these values by those in another array using a row-wise replacement strategy. For example, replacing the vales of `g` by `x`:

```
x = np.array([[2, 3], [4, 5]])
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

to obtain:

```
array([
     [[2, 3], [2, 3], [3, 2]],
     [[4, 4], [5, 4], [5, 5]]])
```

The idea here would be to have the first row of `g` replaced by the first elements of `x` (`0` becomes `2` and `1` becomes `3`) and the same for the other row (the first dimension - number of "rows" - will always be the same for `g` and `x`)

I can't seem to be able to use `np.where` because there's a `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3,2) (2,2) (2,2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC,

```
np.stack([x[i, g[i]] for i in range(x.shape[0])])
```

Output:

```
array([[[2, 3],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 2]],

       [[4, 4],
        [5, 4],
        [5, 5]]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Vectorized approach with [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) to index into the last axis of `x` with `g` using `axis=-1` -

```
In [20]: np.take_along_axis(x[:,None],g,axis=-1)
Out[20]: 
array([[[2, 3],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 2]],

       [[4, 4],
        [5, 4],
        [5, 5]]])
```

Or with manual integer-based indexing -

```
In [27]: x[np.arange(len(g))[:,None,None],g]
Out[27]: 
array([[[2, 3],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 2]],

       [[4, 4],
        [5, 4],
        [5, 5]]])
```

Comment: A vectorized approach is interesting. I'm surprised it takes more or less the same time as the other answers based on list comprehension.

Comment: You can have a look at [this comparaison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46470401/1720199).

Comment: @PedroA Think for a vectorized approach to shine, you need to feed in something bigger than those sample ones.

Comment: @Divakar In this particular case it is faster, but not drastically faster. For example with a 100^3 matrix it takes around 4ms while `np.stack([x[i, g[i]] ...` takes about 6ms and the comprehension about 14.5ms.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, g is an array of indexes (indexes being 0 or 1) and x is the array to who's values you use.

Something like this should work (tested quickly)

```
import numpy as np

def swap_indexes(index_array, array):
   out_array = []
   for i, row in enumerate(index_array):
         out_array.append([array[i,indexes] for indexes in row])
   return np.array(out_array)


index_array = np.array([[[0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]], [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]]])
x = np.array([[2, 3], [4, 5]])
print(swap_indexes(index_array, x))
```

[EDIT: fixed typo that created duplicates]

Comment: >g is an array of indexes This is an interesting approach. I have not looked at it this way but makes sense in the situation I'm using. The function seems to be returning duplicates though. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @PedroA you're right I had a typo in the function, should no longer return duplicates

Answer (score 1):

One solution, is to simply use comprehension directly here:

```py
>>> np.array([[x[i][c] for c in r] for i, r in enumerate(g)])
array([[[2, 3],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 2]],

       [[4, 4],
        [5, 4],
        [5, 5]]])
```