# Python/Numpy without loops: Do function for every slice of multdim np.array

Tags: python, numpy

I have several arrays in a list (think of it as a time series):

```
one_array = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[5,5,5],[0,0,1]])
many_arrays = np.array([one_array, one_array + 1])
```

Now, I want to do the same operation for every matrix in the time series, e.g. I want to calculate the determinant. These two operations give the same result (`-5`):

```
np.linalg.det(one_array)
np.linalg.det(many_arrays[0,:,:])
```

How do I tell Python to `do np.linalg.det(many_arrays[i,:,:]) for every i` without used the dreaded loop? So in this particular example I'd like to get `(-5, -6)` as a return value.

Bonus points: How can I tell Python to `do np.linalg.det(even_more_arrays[i, j, :,:]) for every i, j`?

---

edit: I am looking for a generic way to do this. I understand that np.linalg.det supports this operation. But how do I do it for any function `DO_SOMETHING_WITH_2D_MATRIX` that only takes a 2 dimensional object:

```
DO_SOMETHING_WITH_2D_MATRIX(one_array)
DO_SOMETHING_WITH_2D_MATRIX(many_arrays[0,:,:])
```

Comment: You might want to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
np.linalg.det(many_arrays)

'''
Output:
array([-5., -6.])
'''
```

without slicing `many_arrays`.

As,

> many_arrays[0,:,:] = one_array

Comment: OK, yes, that works. But it works because of some np-magic there, that supports that kind of operation. Suppose I write my own determinant-function. How do I write it in a way that this works?

Comment: That's not magic, you should read NumPy documentation. For writing your own determinant-function, you should try by yourself first. Then if you get any problem/errors, then ask (making a new question for that will be good).

Comment: Thanks you for helping! I think I have not clearly stated my problem. I am NOT interested in calculating the determinant. I am interested in what I called "magic" just before. Maybe you can point me to where to look that up in the NumPy documentation? Because I have not been able to find it.

Comment: [Look up here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating)