# Remove punctuation from numpy string arrays

Tags: python, string, numpy, nlp

The `string` package is useful for stripping punctuation from individual strings as demonstrated below:

```
import string
stripPunct = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)

word = 'foo.bar.baz'

word.translate(stripPunct)

Output: 'foobarbaz'
```

But what is the method to apply this exact same method to every string in a numpy array of strings?

```
myArr =   np.array(['foo.bar.baz', 'foo.bar.baz', 'foo.bar.baz'], dtype='<U15')


myArr.translate(stripPunct)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

Comment: Apologies, I edited the question

Comment: Is `np.array` -> `list` -> `map` or list comprehension -> `np.array` an option for you?

Comment: yes those are good suggestions

Comment: Also have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

Comment: Iterate? `res = [words.translate(stripPunct) for words in myArr] `

Comment: What's the real-world size of your array?  For small arrays like your sample, list comprehension tends to be best, but `np.vectorize` gets better when the array is large (though a pure list solution is best both small and large).  `numpy` does not have specialized string handling code.  Even `np.char.translate` uses the Python `translate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import string
import numpy as np

stripPunct = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)

myArr =  np.array(['foo.bar.baz', 'foo.bar.baz', 'foo.bar.baz'])
# works for 'any.string.inputted'
new = np.array([i.translate(stripPunct) for i in myArr])
```

Output:

```
array(['foobarbaz', 'foobarbaz', 'foobarbaz'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.vectorize` to make a vectorized function.

```py
stripPunct=str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
vecTrans=np.vectorize(lambda x:x.translate(stripPunct))
myArr=np.array(['foo.bar.baz', 'foo.bar.baz', 'foo.bar.baz'], dtype='<U15')

vecTrans(myArr)

>>>return: array(['foobarbaz', 'foobarbaz', 'foobarbaz'], dtype='<U9')
```

Comment: Is that any better than the list comprehension suggestion?