# Efficient way to apply a function to elements of a numpy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have an enormous 1D numpy array of booleans `w` and an increasing list of indices `i`, which splits `w` into `len(i)+1` subarrays. A toy example is:

```
w=numpy.array([True,False,False,False,True,True,True,True,False,False])
i=numpy.array([0,0,2,5,5,8,8])
```

I wish to compute a numpy array `wi`, whose `i`-th entry is 1 if the `i`-th subarray contains a `True` and 0 otherwise. In other words, the `i`-th entry of `w` is the sum (logical 'or') of elements of the `i`-th subarray of `w`. In our example, the output is:

```
[0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]
```

This is achieved with the code:

```
wi=numpy.fromiter(map(numpy.any,numpy.split(w,i)),int)
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this or is this optimal as far as memory is concerned?

P.S. [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency (memory and performance), use [`np.bitwise_or.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) as it keeps the output in boolean -

```
In [10]: np.bitwise_or.reduceat(w,np.r_[0,i])
Out[10]: array([ True,  True, False,  True, False, False])
```

To have as int output, view as `int` -

```
In [11]: np.bitwise_or.reduceat(w,np.r_[0,i]).view('i1')
Out[11]: array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int8)
```

---

Here's *all-weather* solution -

```
def slice_reduce_or(w, i):
    valid = i<len(w)
    invalidc =( ~valid).sum()
    i = i[valid]
    
    mi = np.r_[i[:-1]!=i[1:],True]
    pp = i[mi]
    p1 = np.bitwise_or.reduceat(w,pp)
    
    N = len(i)+1
    out = np.zeros(N+invalidc, dtype=bool)
    out[1:N][mi] = p1
    out[0] = w[:i[0]].any()
    return out.view('i1')
```

Comment: When len(w)=10^7, len(i)=10^7, your method is 164x faster than mine. When len(w)=10^8, len(i)=10^7, your method is 69x faster than mine. I like your all-weather function : ). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let's try `np.add.reductat`:

```
wi = np.add.reduceat(w,np.r_[0,i]).astype(bool)
```

output:

```
array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

And performance:

```
%timeit -n 100 wi = np.add.reduceat(w,np.r_[0,i]).astype(bool).astype(int)
21.7 µs ± 7.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -n 100 wi=np.fromiter(map(np.any,np.split(w,i)),int)
44.5 µs ± 7.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So we're looking at about 2x speed here.

Comment: Hmm, your command does not produce the same results as mine. For `w=[True,False,False,True,False,True,True]; i=[0,0,2,4]`, I get `[0 0 1 1 1]` and you get `[1 1 1 1 1]`.

Comment: Well, sirs, it makes no sense to seriously post nano-"benchmarks" and derive performance expectations, given all data are in-cache. Kindly re-evaluate the tests for data-sizes slightly above 1E+9 elements in each vector ( as numpy is quite storage-efficiency aware ). Given these, real-world sizes, one may claim what strategy brings what storage & processing costs and which one gets higher performance. That's fair, isn't it?

Comment: @user3666197 See my benchmarks in the accepted answer.

Comment: @Leo Exactly, @Divakar is a reliable source of any ultimately performant processing strategy using numpy-tooling. Great step to make it quantitatively re-validated. Using the *pure*-`[SERIAL]`, GIL-dancing, naive **`map()`**-iterator was a one-liner, yet a cost of a lost game since the very beginning - now you know how much acceleration comes from the gems hidden inside `numpy`. Stay well & stay tuned, Leo