# Removing `n` elements from each row in `2D` numpy where `n` varies row by row

Tags: python, numpy

How would one remove `n` elements from `2D` numpy array where `n` varies in each row?

For example:

```
# input array 
[[1,2,3],
 [3,1,2],
 [1,2,3],
 [4,5,2],
 [5,6,7]]
```

with

```
# n elements to remove from each row
[0, 2, 1, 2, 1]
```

would result in:

```
[[1,2,3],
 [3],
 [1, 2],
 [4],
 [5,6]]
```

Do note that the result does not need to be a numpy array(and won't be as Michael noticed in the comments), just an arbitrary Python list of lists.

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid `numpy` `np.array`.

Comment: what is the logic of removing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, the result wouldn't be a numpy array.

Given the example data from your question:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],
...  [3,1,2],
...  [1,2,3],
...  [4,5,2],
...  [5,6,7]]
>>> remove_n_tail_list = [0, 2, 1, 2, 1]
```

You could for example use a list comprehension to get the desired result:

```
>>> [row[:len(row) - remove_n_tail] for row, remove_n_tail in zip(a, remove_n_tail_list)]
[[1, 2, 3], [3], [1, 2], [4], [5, 6]]
```

In that solution, `row[:len(row) - remove_n_tail]` is selecting the values up to the length of the row (`len(row)`), minus the number of values you want to remove from the end (`remove_n_tail`).

There are various methods to achieve similar results. You might find the [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array) question interesting.

Comment: @adirabargil you are right. An alternative faster solution could be a good contribution. I'd certainly be interested.

Answer (score 2):

Herewith I have come up with a solution. Give it a try:

```py
arr = [[1,2,3],
 [3,1,2],
 [1,2,3],
 [4,5,2],
 [5,6,7]]
new_arr =[]
lst = [0, 2, 1, 2, 1]
count=0
for i in arr:
    remove = lst[count]
    count = count+1
    temp = i[:len(i)-remove]
    new_arr.append(temp)
print(new_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `arr` is your `numpy` array, `rem` is a list of removal-counts, a simple solution could be:

```
res = [arr[i][:3-rem[i]].tolist() for i in range(len(rem))]
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3], [1, 2], [4], [5, 6]]
```