# In numpy, apply N percentiles to an N x M array _respectively_

Tags: numpy

Is this something that can be done cleanly in numpy without a for loop?

```
percentiles = np.array([50, 100])
data = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

I want the 50th percentile of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and the 100th percentile of `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`, *not* both the 50th and 100th of both.

Can this be done in an efficient way without for loops?

thanks

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: This post about [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array) should help