# Iterating through a numpy array /matrix and storing it in a seperate array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I have a matrix/numpy array A and need to carry out a function f to all elements and then store the result in a matrix B. How would I do this, I'm thinking of appending an empty array of B as I go on but is this the best way of doing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

Comment: Tell us about `A` - shape and dtype.  Also about `f`. What kind of input does it accept?

Comment: If the function only takes scalar values, it is hard to beat a list comprehension on a 1d list. If you've been told you should use `numpy` take some time to learn its basics. Poorly written `numpy` won't save you time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
A = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
#array([[0, 1, 2],
#       [3, 4, 5],
#       [6, 7, 8]])

my_func = lambda x: x + 1 #Example function
vect_func = np.vectorize(my_func)
B = vect_func(A)
```

Output

```
print(B)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Most operations can be done directly on the array itself. For example, if you want to add one to each element of the array, you would simply call;

```
arr2 = arr1+1
```

Vectorizing may be necessary if the required operation isn't universal, but will be at the expense of execution time. Vectorizing a function will still result in a looped operation, where as the universal functions (like above) are performed as scalars.