# How to use an isinstance qualifier on the elements of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I can do

```py
arr = np.random.randint(0, 1, size=(10,10))
arr == 1
```

and get a boolean array as an output.

What if my array is an `object` data type and I want to check that certain elements are an instance of some class? Is there a **native** way to do it?

Comment: The first line makes a (10,10) array of `int` dtype and all values 0.  The second line replaces it with a scalar `1`.  I don't see where you get an boolean array.  Nor do I see `object` dtype array.

Comment: For an object dtype array, you check the `isinstance` of the objects the same way as you would in a list..  Other than allowing things like `reshape`, object dtype array adds nothing to lists.

Comment: Oops, I see that you  used `==` not `=`.  I wish people would show the output of their code.  I do that all time in my answers.  But I don't see the relevance of that to the `isinstance` question. The boolean aray has a `bool` dtype.  Checking the array `dtype` is different from checking element class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) is an option that `numpy` provides for doing so:

```
>>> np_isinstance = np.vectorize(isinstance)
>>> np_isinstance(arr, str)

array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False]])
```

But see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array) about efficiency; it is basically doing a for loop, so there aren't the same efficiency benefits of built-in `numpy` methods.  Other options are also discussed on the thread, if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks for that and the heads up. Will leave it open for a bit before marking as answered