# Operation on specific array position based on boolean map, boolean mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masked-array

I want to have the code to do certain operations on the specified elements of the array based on a boolean map.

Let's say I have a numpy array.

`a = np.array([[-2.5,-3.2],[2.3,5.3],[1.9,-2.8]])`

I want to do certain operations, such as `np.ceil()` for all the negative elements but not on the positive elements.

I know you could create a boolean mask by doing
`mask = a<0`

However, if you do this `np.ceil(a[mask])`, this will only output `array([-2., -3., -2.])`

I want to have the output as
`array([[-2., -3.], [ 2.3,  5.3], [ 1.9, -2.]])`

I know you could write a loop to do this. I am asking for an easier, cleaner solution.

Comment: `a[a<0] = np.ceil(a[a<0])`

Answer (score 0):

One trivial way of doing it is:

```
a[a<0]=np.ceil(a[a<0])
#array([[-2. , -3. ],
#       [ 2.3,  5.3],
#       [ 1.9, -2. ]])
```

A better solution, which does not modify `a` inplace, is to use masked arrays that are constructed for this purpose exactly:

```
np.ma.ceil(np.ma.masked_greater_equal(a, 0)).data
#array([[-2. , -3. ],
#       [ 2.3,  5.3],
#       [ 1.9, -2. ]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers! Mask is what I was looking for. This relies on the np.ma.ceil function which is provided by NumPy. What if it's a custom user-defined function? Is there a way to map a function to a masked array?

Answer (score -1):

You might try something like this. This is one way you can apply the function `np.ceil` if the number is negative, else just leave it alone.

```
    result = np.array([
        [
            np.ceil(num) if num < 0 else num
            for num
            in s
        ]
        for s
        in a
    ])
```

You might also check here
[Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)