# Extract and then map a column in a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am learning numpy...

I have an 2d array like:

```
myArray = np.array([['0','1'], ['0','1'], ['1','0'], ['1','0']])
```

Also I am given a columnIndex (example: `1`)

so I need to extract the column and for each element, if it is "0" return "a", if it is "1" return "b".

```
myArray[:, columnIndex]
> ['1' '1' '0' '0']
```

Then

```
f = lambda x: 'a' if x is '0' else 'b'
f(selected)
> ['1' '1' '0' '0']
```

But I expect

```
> ['b', 'b', 'a', 'a']
```

I originally tried `f = lambda x: 'a' if x == '0' else 'b'` and got

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Why this happens? How can I cleanly extract and convert a column in an 2d numpy array?

Comment: Why do you expect a 2d array? your expected result `['b', 'b', 'a', 'a']` is 1d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an array as a conditional in your `if` clause, that why you get the error

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

It's also not quite clear what `selected` is, I guess it's `myArray[:, columnIndex]`.

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import numpy as np

column_index = 1
myArray = np.array([['0','1'], ['0','1'], ['1','0'], ['1','0']])
selected = myArray[:, column_index]

result = ['a' if x == '0' else 'b' for x in selected]
print(result) # ['b' 'b' 'a' 'a']
```

I'd prefer to use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), to select one of two options element-wise, based on a condition:

```
result = np.where(selected == '0', 'a', 'b')
print(result) # ['b' 'b' 'a' 'a']
```

For the small example given here the list comprehension is faster, but I expect the numpy solution to be  faster for larger arrays. Do note that `numpy.where` will return a `numpy.ndarray` instead of a list.

Comment: Great answer!--

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation. You are right, `selected = myArray[:, columnIndex]`. Now I learned the "list comprehension" and numpy `where` . Awesome!

Comment: @nacho4d My pleasure. List comprehensions are concise and powerful, and very fun! I added a link to the documentation as well.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `f` does not get applied to the elements individually here, but to the array as a whole. What you're missing is a call to [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) or [other comparable approaches](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46470401/261142).