# Create 2d array from 2 single dimensional array in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have 2 single-dimensional NumPy arrays

```
a = np.array([0, 4])
b = np.array([3, 2])
```

I want to create a 2d array of numbers

```
c = np.array([[0,1,2], [4,5]])
```

I can also create this using a for loop

EDIT: Updating loop based on [@jtwalters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3508556/jtwalters) comments

```
c = np.zeros(b.shape[0], dtype=object)
for i in range(b.shape[0]):
    c[i] = np.arange(a[i], a[i]+b[i])
```

How can I achieve this via vectorization/broadcasting?

Comment: `[[0,1,2], [4,5]]`  **cannot** be made into a 2d array.

Comment: Does `np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)` work for you?

Comment: I agree with your first comment. But `np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)` won't work. 2 rows should be `np.arange(a[i], a[i]+b[i])` please note that `3` is not in my resulting array.

Comment: I was trying make sense out of a confusing example.

Comment: Your loop does not work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have made edits based on @jwalters comments.

Comment: When you come up with a 2d array target we can talk "vectorization".   For what you currently want, lists will be just as good, maybe even faster.  Look at your `c`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an ndarray from ragged nested sequences you must put `dtype=object`.

For example:

```py
c = np.empty(b.shape[0], dtype=object)
for i in range(b.shape[0]):
    c[i] = np.arange(a[i], a[i]+b[i])
```

Or with [array for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array):

```py
np.array([np.arange(a[i], a[i]+b[i]) for i in range(b.shape[0])], dtype=object)
```

Vectorized:

```
def func(a, b):
  return np.arange(a, a + b)

vfunc = np.vectorize(func, otypes=["object"])
vfunc([0, 4], [3, 2])
```

Comment: Is there a way to vectorize this?

Comment: @deepAgrawal Yes, I update the code with `np.vectorize`