# Apply custom function/operator between numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

There are two arrays and I want to get distance between two arrays based on known individual elements distance.

```
dist = {(4,3): 0.25, (4,1):0.75, (0,0):0, (3,3):0, (2,1):0.25, (1,0): 0.25}
a = np.array([[4, 4, 0], [3, 2, 1]])
b = np.array([[3, 1, 0]])

a
array([[4, 4, 0],
       [3, 2, 1]])
b
array([[3, 1, 0]])

expected output based on dictionary dist:
array([[0.25, 0.75, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.25, 0.25]])
```

So, if we need which elements are different we can do `a!=b`. Similarly, instead of `!=`, I want to apply the below function -

```
def get_distance(a, b):
    return dist[(a, b)]
```

to get the expected output above.

I tried `np.vectorize(get_distance)(a, b)` and it works. But I am not sure if it is the best way to do the above in vectorized way. So, for two numpy arrays, what is the best way to apply custom function/operator?

Comment: May be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35215161/8033585

Comment: numpy.apply_along_axis() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing your distance mapping as a `dict`, use a `np.array` for lookup (or possibly a sparse matrix if size becomes an issue).

```
d = np.zeros((5, 4))
for (x, y), z in dist.items():
    d[x, y] = z
```

Then, simply index.

```
>>> d[a, b]
array([[0.25, 0.75, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.25, 0.25]])
```

---

For a sparse solution (code is almost identical):

```
In [14]: from scipy import sparse

In [15]: d = sparse.dok_matrix((5, 4))

In [16]: for (x, y), z in dist.items():
    ...:     d[x, y] = z
    ...:

In [17]: d[a, b].A
Out[17]:
array([[0.25, 0.75, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.25, 0.25]])
```

Comment: Good one. I think it can not get better than this. I got stuck with dictionary.