# Create new numpy array from existing numpy array by applying some functions for each element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need this functionality, but by using numpy arrays instead of python lists

```
my_list = ['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
new_list = list()    
for elem in my_list:
    new_list.append(func(elem))
```

for loop consumes lot of time and cpu if the list becomes large. So I need this functionality with numpy array. Help out!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

Comment: As long as `func` has to be applied once to every element of the list, there isn't a `numpy` way of improving on this.  Iteration on a list is faster than on an array.  `numpy` code is fast, if you start with arrays, and apply the compiled  whole-array methods.

Comment: You don't tell us anything about `func`, but `my_list` contains strings/characters. `numpy` does not have any fast compiled methods for strings.  The fast stuff is for numbers.  String dtype is ok for basic array operations like reshape, but for work on individual elements it depends on Python string methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp)

> The map() function executes a specified function for each item in an iterable. The item is sent to the function as a parameter.

```
np.array(list(map(func, my_list)))
```

Comment: In my experience `map` and list comprehensions run about the same.  And only modestly faster than the OP's for/append.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, you can [vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)  `func` to make it more elegant, and remove this `for-loop`.

```py
import numpy as np

def func(v):
    return v ** 2

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
vfunc = np.vectorize(func)
array = vfunc(my_list)
```

The above results with this:

```
array([1, 4, 9, 16])
```

Comment: That's for convenience, not speed.  And as many SO questions show, using `np.vectorize` has pitfalls.