# Most efficient way to map function on numpy array using cell information and location

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, mapping

I have a corpus with *m* documents and *n* unique words.

Based on this corpus, I want to calculate a co-occurrence matrix for words and calculate their similarity.

To do so, I have created a NumPy array `occurrences` (*m x n*), which indicates which words are present in each document.

Based on the `occurrences`, I have created `cooccurrences` as follows:

```
cooccurrences = np.transpose(occurrences) @ occurrences
```

Furthermore, `word_occurrences` gives the sum per word in the corpus:

```
word_occurrences = occurrences.sum(axis=0)
```

Now, I want to calculate the similarity scores of words in `cooccurrences` based on the association strength.

I want to divide each cell *i, j* in `cooccurrences`, by `word_occurrences[i] * word_occurrences[j]`.

Currently, I loop through `cooccurrences` to do this.

```
def calculate_association_strength(cooc, i, j, word_occurrences):
        return cooc/(word_occurrences[i]*word_occurrences[j])


for i in range(len(cooccurrences)):
            for j in range(len(cooccurrences)):
                if i != j:
                    if cooccurrences[i,j] > 0 :
                        cooccurrences[i,j] = 1 - self.calculate_association_strength(cooccurrences[i,j], i,j,word_occurrences)
                else:
                    cooccurrences[i,j] = 0
```

But with *m* > 30 000, this is very time-consuming. Is there a faster way to do this?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array), they discuss mapping a function on a np.array. However, they don't use multiple variables derived from the array.

Comment: you may want to take into account counts of words in each document. It will help you differentiate similar VS very similar documents. Second thing - could you make [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I don't know numpy but I can imagine that a numpy-specific approach would be good. Nevertheless, two observations: `word_occurrences[i]*word_occurrences[j]` can be calculated in advance for each `i, j` combination (EDIT: you should be able to save half the calculations `i, j` is the same as `j, i`). This might speed up things a little bit. Also, the final result for each cell does not depend on the other cell values. Your algorithm can be parallelized easily.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the problem here correctly, you could vectorise the whole operation, so the result would be:

`cooccurrences / word_occurrences.reshape(-1,1) * word_occurrences`

This is pretty much guaranteed to work faster than looping through the array.

Comment: Thank you for your response @w_sz. Unfortunately, your suggested approach results in a different matrix than I currently have.

Comment: I must have messed up the dimensions then. I edited the answer and think that if You reshape the other matrix its going to work as intended

Comment: Thanks again. Still, this results in a different matrix.

Comment: It worked for me when I compared them with `np.isclose()` so perhaps there might be a very small difference.