# Specifically change all elements in a numpy array based on a condition without iterating over each element

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Hi I would like to **change all the values** in this array (test) simultaneously based on a second boolean array (test_map) **without iterating over each item**.

```
test = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
test_map = np.array([True,False,False,False,False,False,False,True])
test[test_map] = random.randint(0,1)
```

output:

```
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])  or  array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

The problem with this is that I want the values that should be changed (in this case the first and last value) to each randomly be changed to a 0 or 1. So the 4 possible outputs should be:

```
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])  or  array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])  or  array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])  or  array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Check out numpy vectorizer.
Here's a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35215329/11034814

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to generate a random array of "bits", with `np.random.randint`:

```py
import numpy as np

test = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
test_map = np.array([True,False,False,False,False,False,False,True])
# array of random 1/0 of the same length as test
r = np.random.randint(0, 2, len(test))
test[test_map] = r[test_map]
test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate just as many random integers as you need by passing the number of `True` values in `test_map` as the `size` argument to `np.random.randint()`:

```py
test[test_map] = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=np.sum(test_map))
```