# How to turn a multi-label np.array to one vs all?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have an `np.array` with several labels, let's say `label1`, ..., `label10`.

Given a specific label, let's say `label1`. I want to turn it to a binary vector where `y'[j] == 1` iff `y[j] == label1`

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple comparison:

```
>>> np.array([f'label{i}' for i in range(10)])
array(['label0', 'label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4', 'label5',
       'label6', 'label7', 'label8', 'label9'], dtype='<U6')
>>> ar = np.array([f'label{i}' for i in range(10)])
>>> ar == 'label1'
array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False])
```

If you want a binary vector:

```
>>> (ar == 'label1').astype(int)
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a fine way:

```
import numpy as np
label = 'label1'
tobinary = lambda val: 1 if val == label else 0

vfunc = np.vectorize(tobinary)
vfunc(y)
```

relying on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35215329/3880275)