# matplotlib different values for y function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to make plot for:
[this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFX3S.png) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXXha.png)

I made plots before with this code:

```
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
y1 = np.tanh(x)
plt.plot(x,y1)
```

but how to make something like this?

```
 if(x <= 0):
    y4 = 0
else:
    y4 = x
```

gives valueerror:The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: `y1 = x.clip(min=0)`

Comment: `np.where` for your second function.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for the first one! 
i still struggle to make the second, tried y5a = x.clip(min=0) and y5b = np.e**x-1 but dont know how to merge it

Answer (score 0):

Try this iterate over the array and apply the function:

```
def relu(x):
    if(x <= 0):
        y4 = 0
    else:
        y4 = x
    return y4

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
array_for = np.array([relu(element) for element in x])
plt.plot(array_for)
```

[image]

alternatively, you can use numpy.vectorize or another solution
posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46470401/15879103).

Answer (score 0):

You see the error because the result of x<0 gives multiple boolean (one per each element of x). Hence the if cannot resolve whether the condition is true or false.

In your case, you can simply compute y and then change its values based on conditions on x:

```
x=np.arange(-2, 2, 1)
y=np.exp(x)-1

# check content of y
print(y)


y[x<0]=0

# check updated content of y
print(y)
```