# Numpy: Boolean operation on np.array passed into function

Tags: python, numpy, boolean-operations

Numpy allows to pass a `numpy.array` as argument into a function and evaluate the function for every element of the array.:

```py
def f(n):
    return n**2

arr = np.array([1,2,3])
f(arr)
```

outputs:

```py
>>>[1 4 9]
```

This works fine, as long as `f(n)`doesn't perform boolean operations on `n` like this:

```py
def f(n):
    if n%2 == 0:
        print(n)
```

The above code throws following exception:
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

This makes sense since the debugger showed, that the function `f(n)` received the entire `numpy.array`as input. Now, I'm looking for a way to change the code behaviour, so that I can perform boolean operations on the inputs. Is this possible while passing the entire `numpy.array`, or do I have to call the function by manually iterating over each element of the array?

---Edit:---

```
def get_far_field_directivity(k,a,theta):
    temp = k*a*np.sin(theta)
    if temp == 0: return 1
    else: return (2*sp.jn(1,(temp)))/(temp)
```

The function returns to other functions, which have to use its value on further calculation which is why the indexing approach by @Chrysophylaxs won't work.

Comment: ^ is bitwise XOR, so you are just doing this arr^2, and it outputs `array([3, 0, 1], dtype=int32)` is that what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't mean that. This isn't the actual piece of code, I'm working on, so I didn't notice. I meant to square it - Sorry :-(

Comment: Well, what behavior do you want? Print every element where the condition is true?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. This is just a minimal working example. So this might seem kind of useless.

Comment: I think it would help to clarify your requirements. Are you specifically wanting to call `f()` for each element in the array, or is the function `f()` just part of a solution you aren't getting to work quite right?

Comment: I've just clarified the question. I have to call `f()`on every single element.

Comment: This may help then: [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35215161/13843268).

Comment: This would work however, I'm trying to avoid this solution, since in the real application, I have 3 Arrays with x,y,z Coorinates and passing the `np.arrays`, which actually are a meshgrid could get quite hairy and unelegant.

Comment: The basic problem is that an array, or condition on an array, cannot be used in an `if`.  `if` is a simple True/False branch.  It does not do any sort of iteration.  You have to do the iteration yourself, e.g. `for x in y: if x>0: do something`.  There are many, many, SO about this `ambiguity` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want to try something like this? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2,3])

def f(n):
    if n%2 == 0:
        print(n)
    return n**2

vfunc = np.vectorize(f)      
vfunc(arr)
```

outputs:

```py
2
array([1, 4, 9])
```

whereas this

```py
f(arr)
```

outputs:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example step by step with input `np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`:

- First `n%2` is executed, which returns `np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1])`, which is the elementwise modulo 2.
- Next, the resulting array is elementwise compared to 0, which results in: `np.array([False, True, False, True, False])`.
- Finally, this array is checked for truthyness in the `if` statement. That is where the problem occurs, because the array contains multiple elements, and numpy can't be sure whether you intend this to be `True` or `False`.

I suspect that instead you want to print all of the values in the input array whose modulo 2 equals 0. If that is the case, you can do that by filtering those out by indexing using the boolean array:

```
def f(n):
    evens = n[ n%2 == 0 ]
    print(evens)
```

```
Input:   f(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
Output:  array([2, 4])
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, since I have to return a value in the condition. If the condition is not met, I return another value. The above code is just a minimal working example, but I will add the actual function in question.