# Vectorize a Python function (REFPROP 9.1)

Tags: python, dataframe, list, vectorization

I have a dataframe `data`. I have a column `data['T']` and a column `data['p']`.
When using a function called `TPFLSHdll` I get the following error
`TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`
The code is the following:

```
import os
from ctREFPROP.ctREFPROP import REFPROPFunctionLibrary

# connetto Python alle librerie REFPROP (prende in automatico la cartella)
RP = REFPROPFunctionLibrary(os.environ['RPPREFIX'])
RP.SETPATHdll(os.environ['RPPREFIX'])

RP.SETUPdll(1, 'WATER.FLD', "HMX.BNC","DEF")

D, Dl, Dv, x, y, q, e, h, s, Cv, Cp, w, ierr, herr = RP.TPFLSHdll(data['T'], data['P'], [1])
```

I experienced a similar trouble in the past, solved in the following:

```
import os
from ctREFPROP.ctREFPROP import REFPROPFunctionLibrary

# connetto Python alle librerie REFPROP (prende in automatico la cartella)
RP = REFPROPFunctionLibrary(os.environ['RPPREFIX'])
RP.SETPATHdll(os.environ['RPPREFIX'])

RP.SETUPdll(1, 'WATER.FLD', "HMX.BNC","DEF")

D, Dl, Dv, x, y, q, e, h, s, Cv, Cp, w, ierr, herr = RP.TPFLSHdll(data['T'].values, data['P'].values, [1])
```

This solution to add `.values` doesn't work and I get the following `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Any suggestion to avoid FOR cycle?

Comment: you cannot. Vectorization relies on using pandas/numpy built-in functions.

Comment: your function clearly expects a float as an argument, you cannot magically make it work on array inputs. And if you have a python-level function, you cannot really get much speed gains if you want to apply it to every element. Here are some alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array