# numpy lambda with output of more than one

Tags: python, numpy, performance

Is it possible to do the following with lambda?
(I just need something which is able to do this really fast)

Asking for lambda because of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35216364/3776738

```
import numpy as np

def one_to_more(i):
    //do some calculations etc...
    return [i*3,i*9]

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
f = lambda x: one_to_more(x)
more = f(x)
print(more)
```

---> `[3,9,6,18,9,27]`

EDIT: IT MUST NOT BE LAMBDA. I'm just looking for the fastest method to extend a large list or numpy array this way. This way means that it will have twice (the example code above or even longer length)

**CLEANED**:

this is the actual function used:

```
MAX_NUM=100000
def num_to_arr (num):
    num = int(num) 
    if (num < 0 or num >= MAX_NUM):
        num = 0

    num3 = (num // 1600)
    num2 = ((num - num3 * 1600) // 40)
    num1 = int((num - num3 * 1600 - num2 * 40))
    arr = [num1 / 40, num2 / 40, num3 / 40]
    return arr
```

used like this:

```
result=list(map(num_to_arr,large_array))
```

The large array consist of about 10k integers and the execution time is about 17ms which is much too high. (CPU IS AMD RYZEN 7950X)

Comment: I just thought lambda can  do this the fastest way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35216364/3776738

Comment: A lambda is not going to be "faster", What is limiting here? Are you going to call this one time or millions of times? What is the shape of your input array? only 3 or larger?

Comment: @user3776738 a lambda expression doesn't affect speed at all. It is syntactic sugar for creating a function object using an expression, instead of requiring a statement. It has *no bearing on performance*

Comment: It will be used on very large arrays. I'm just looking for the fastest method to extend arrays this way.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have edited the question to make it more clear. I don't think that the function can be vectorized.

Comment: "but the concatenation process of list or np.array is very slow," for a `list` it is not. For arrays it is. Again, you really need to clarify **what it is you are actually asking**

Comment: It can be numpy or list, that doesn't matter. All that matters is that it gets done faster, by a lot.

Comment: You misunderstood that link about `lambda`.  That is contrasting a direct `numpy` calculation with `np.vectorize` or a list comprehension; the lambda wrapper is just a quick way of writing a function for testing and timing.

Comment: OK, I have added the actual function.

Comment: So, for example, if `result = []` then `for _ in range(1_000_000): result += [None, None]` takes `106 ms` on my relatively old machine. That is not your bottleneck

Comment: I have added the use of the function and the time.

Comment: Can you please clean up your question? There is a bunch of irrelevant stuff there.

Comment: It's cleaned now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, thank you for providing your actual question. I created a version of your function which works on the entire array and uses some vectorization (although, it isn't fully vectorized). This provided pretty good improvement, though:

```
In [5]: MAX_NUM = 5000

In [6]: def num_to_arr (num):
    ...:     num = int(num)
    ...:     if (num < 0 or num >= MAX_NUM):
    ...:         num = 0
    ...:
    ...:     num3 = (num // 1600)
    ...:     num2 = ((num - num3 * 1600) // 40)
    ...:     num1 = int((num - num3 * 1600 - num2 * 40))
    ...:     arr = [num1 / 40, num2 / 40, num3 / 40]
    ...:     return arr
    ...:

In [7]: def num_to_arr_vec(arr):
    ...:     arr[(arr < 0) | (arr >= MAX_NUM)] = 0
    ...:     result = np.zeros((len(arr), 3))
    ...:     result[:,2] = arr//1600
    ...:     result[:,1] = ((arr - result[:,2] * 1600) // 40)
    ...:     result[:,0] = (arr - result[:,2] * 1600 - result[:,1] * 40)
    ...:     return result / 40
    ...:

In [8]: arr = np.random.randint(-10_000, 10_000, 10_000)

In [9]: %timeit list(map(num_to_arr, arr))
6.72 ms ± 234 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit num_to_arr_vec(arr)
333 µs ± 6.46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

So it's about 20x faster. I suspect to do better, you would want to use [`numba` here and write a very imperative loop](https://numba.pydata.org/)

EDIT:

Add `numba` example:

```
In [51]: import numba

In [52]: @numba.jit(numba.float64[:,:](numba.int64[:]), nopython=True)
    ...: def num_to_arr_numba(arr):
    ...:     result = np.empty((len(arr), 3))
    ...:     for i in range(len(arr)):
    ...:         num = arr[i]
    ...:         if num < 0 or num >= MAX_NUM:
    ...:             num = 0
    ...:         num3 = num // 1600
    ...:         num2 = ((num - num3 * 1600) // 40)
    ...:         num1 = (num - num3 * 1600 - num2 * 40)
    ...:         result[i, 0] = num1
    ...:         result[i, 1] = num2
    ...:         result[i, 2] = num3
    ...:     result /= 40
    ...:     return result
    ...:

In [53]: %timeit num_to_arr_numba(arr)
85.7 µs ± 2.64 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

So this seems to bring us to about an 80x faster.

Comment: That's a real nice improvement. Thank you. 20x is good. But I will look into numba as it is not enough for my needs.

Comment: What is this technique called, that you used, so I can do it myself for other functions?

Comment: @user3776738 it's just vectorization. Note, you could probably immediately improve it using [`numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) since this creates a lot of unnecessary intermediate arrays, and the code would be trivial to convert

Comment: @user3776738 btw, I added a `numba` example

Comment: That is amazing.  Can this even be combined with the vectorization method from above and get us to 100x+?

Comment: @user3776738 no, not at all actually. "Vectorization" is just using built-in numpy methods. Those are already running at C-speed, using numba to invoke them doesn't make them faster, and probably won't materially affect the runtime, although you can try

Answer (score 2):

You can use broadcasting and [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
def one_to_more(i):
    return (np.array([3, 9])*i[:,None]).ravel()

out = one_to_more(x)
```

Output: `array([ 3,  9,  6, 18,  9, 27])`

Comment: I have edited the question to make the problem more clear. (There will be done some more stuff with i as a simple multiplication.)

Comment: Unfortunately, it will be difficult to help you without knowing exactly what you are doing in this function. You have two main options: 1) the code can be vectorized and you can remove any python loop, 2) the code can't be vectorized easily and you might want to parallelize.

Comment: @mozway eh, I would reach for `numba` first

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes true