Numpy array of array into array of length (vectorization)
I have a numpy array of arrays, where each sub-array represents a group of elements. I want to compute the length of each sub-array and store the result as a new numpy array.
Currently, I use a standard for loop, but I would like to vectorize this operation for better performance using only numpy.
Example
import numpy as np

indices = np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5]), np.array([6, 7, 8, 9])], dtype=object)
group_lengths = np.array([len(group) for group in indices])

print(group_lengths)

Expected output
[3 2 4]
I am looking for a fully vectorized solution that avoids the explicit loop. How can this be achieved with numpy?
Update
Thank you all for your insights and clarifications! I now understand that fully vectorizing my use case isn't possible. I'll stick with my current solution, as it seems to be the most efficient approach given the circumstances.

It cannot be optimised further than what you already have. You have a "jagged" array, which does not fit with the numpy memory model. If anything, you'd be better without numpy at all

"I would like to vectorize this operation for better performance" This is not possible. The reason is that the array contains Numpy objects. Vectorization applies on native types, not objects. Numpy is meant to be fast on native types. For objects, it is not better than lists performance-wise (in fact, it is often slower).

related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array

Currently the best option is to use np.fromiter. This solution was proposed in the comments by Jérôme Richard:
# generate big dataset
indices = np.array([np.random.randint(0,10,size=np.random.randint(4,500))
                    for _ in range(100000)
                    ], dtype=object)

Use map function:
group_lengths = np.array(list(map(len, indices)))
# 6.49 ms ± 57.5 μs per loop

Use list generator with len function
group_lengths = np.array([len(group) for group in indices])
# 8.19 ms ± 60.5 μs per loop

Using numpy vectorized:
vfunc = np.vectorize(len)
group_lengths = vfunc(indices)
# 4.86 ms ± 23.2 μs per loop

Apply the function via np.fromiter
group_lengths = np.fromiter(map(len, indices), dtype=object)
# 3.53 ms ± 36.2 μs per loop 


np.vectorize is just a CPython loop internally so it is not efficient. Its name is confusing : it does not vectorize the operation. It is just provided for convenience, not speed.

thx for the info

Moreover, the two first one are not vectorized operation. map is a generator and list will iterate over the generated objects (list use a vectorized code but AFAIK not map). This tends to be slow though it might possibly be a bit faster than the initial code. For the second one generator loop are generally faster than loop statement but still slow.

@JérômeRichard: yes, I linked to the docs in my answer. But my %timeit lines do not agree... Which surprised me as well. I do not incidentally get the same timeits at all as stated in this answer. For N = 1_000_000, I get: 134 ms, 144 ms, 57.5 ms for option 1, 2, and 3 (np.vectorize) respectively. Any idea what might be the cause, if np.vectorize is really also just a loop?

@ouroboros1 I made tests per loop. here are my results: 5.97 μs - for map, 6.93 μs for list generator, 6.66 μs for np.vectorize.

@ouroboros1 This does not means the loop is vectorized. Python loops can have different performance regarding how the code is written exactly. For example, generator loops tends to be faster. Moreover, accessing globals is generally more expensive than locals. In some cases, like string it can even impact the complexity of the resulting code. In interpreted codes, tiny details can impact performance.

@ouroboros1 Note that if a Numpy function is written in C does not mean it is fully vectorized either because a loop iterating on objects still has to do much of the work of the interpreter internally, that is ref counting, function calls, indirection, allocations, GIL-locking, type checking, etc. Not to mention the code cannot benefit much advanced compiler optimization due to the very-dynamic operations. Such operations are the biggest source of overheads in CPython.

@JérômeRichard: In my answer I am not claiming that np.vectorize is using vectorization. I merely noted apparent serious performance improvement if I use it on a larger version of indices, which as mentioned, also surprised me (knowing it isn't vectorized).

For timings like <10 µs, profiling tends to be a waste of time for Numpy functions. Calling a Numpy function is pretty expensive (often > µs). This overhead can be theoretically significantly reduced, but this is complicated to do (I tried but there was too much work so I finally gave up ^^") and it is pretty hard to explain at this scale for Numpy end-users. It is better to do tests on wider arrays.

@ouroboros1 I just did a quick check on my Windows PC and I get : 544 µs VS 868 µs for your code. Then if I specify the target type, I get : 544 µs VS 687 µs. The list generation alone takes 510 µs. They probably use a faster way to fill the final Numpy array. np.array is very generic and often inefficient.

The best version found so far is np.fromiter(map(len, indices), dtype=object). It is still not (fully) vectorized hence slow but at least faster than others. It is faster than creating a list because it better use memory (caches, better locality of reference counting, etc.). It still calls (multiple) CPython functions for each item which is pretty inefficient. A C code can certainly do much better but is will far from being as fast as native-typed fully-vectorized operations.

I have updated my benchmarks. On small datasets map outperforms np.vectorized, but on large datasets np.vectorized is preferable.

@JohnnyCheesecutter Interrestingly the gap is not so big with np.vectorize on my machine. Note the above solution is significantly faster than all the ones you provide on my machine ;) .

@JérômeRichard you are right. np.fromiter is the best choice found so far.

How does list(map...)) perform - without the conversion to array?

Looks like fromiter with object dtype is the closest thing to list(). - time and result wise.  But does that hurt downstream processing of the array?  For example a sum, cumsum, or scaling?

numpy being optimized for fixed-size arrays, proper vectorization is probably not possible. There is np.vectorize, but as stated in the docs:

[This] function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

It can be used as follows:
np.vectorize(len)(indices)

array([3, 2, 4])

Despite the caveat in the docs, there does seem to be a noticeable performance improvement on larger arrays:
import numpy as np

N = 10_000

indices = np.array(
    [np.array([1, 2, 3]) if i % 2 == 0 else np.array([1,2]) for i in range(N)], 
    dtype=object
    )

%timeit np.vectorize(len)(indices)
%timeit np.array([len(group) for group in indices])

Output:
597 µs ± 11.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
1.22 ms ± 143 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

On a very small example you seem to be paying for the overhead:
indices = np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5]), np.array([6, 7, 8, 9])], 
                   dtype=object)

%timeit np.vectorize(len)(indices)
%timeit np.array([len(group) for group in indices])

Output:
11.7 µs ± 378 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
1.61 µs ± 42.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)


Mmmm, I have some very suspicious squinty eyes whilst looking at these results :P That speedup does not match the docs at all

@roganjosh: I know, I'm surprising myself as well, to be honest. Care to give it a try as well, and share the results you get?

I'm trying to figure out what might be the root cause before I actually play (I can't test just now). But I bet there is something to do with the np.array() constructor itself at play here. If you remove numpy from the scene altogether I think that might be an interesting result

That downvote isn't mine btw. It would be nice if someone could comment why since this answer makes a pretty reasonable effort to time it out, even if I suspect something is missing

@roganjosh: yes, always nice these downvotes without explanation... Nm. The np.array() constructor note is not a bad idea. Using indices = np.array([[1, 2, 3] if i % 2 == 0 else [1,2] for i in range(N)], dtype=object) gets me similar results though.

I mean to literally get rid of numpy everywhere. Having an object type with a jagged array just screws with the point of numpy in the first place. Just have it as a regular list comp

Even though the OP wants an array output, I suspect it's running on the idea that numpy is just inherently faster at everything. I've seen people use np.add() on scalars in the past, thinking it faster than base python, which is just grossly inefficient. It could be a misapprehension from the very start here

Yes, I've noted in the past that for large inputs, a np.vectorize version can be modestly faster than an explicit loop.  Using otypes helps.

@roganjosh Actually, I’m working with the trimesh library, which relies heavily on numpy for handling mesh data like vertices, faces, and edges. In this context, facets are indeed represented as arrays of arrays. So, using numpy is not just about speed but also about compatibility with the underlying data structures.
