# How to fasten up numpy.where() call for a 16000x16000 matrix

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I've got a `16000x16000` matrix and I need to extract a **boolean** mask from it.
The **boolean** mask indicates whether the value at a certain cell is higher than a THRESHOLD or not.

Here's the relevant snippet

```
def adj_mask( dmat ):
    '''
    Returns locations where value exceeds the threshold
    '''
    global DIST    

    return numpy.where(dmat > DIST)
```

I have various matrices for which I need to perform such selection. However, my whole system seems to almost freeze (hang) when I call it with a big (`16000x16000`) matrix.

Please suggest how can I fasten up this computation?

Comment: You've got 256 *million* values to query in a matrix of that size... some suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351255/techniques-for-working-with-large-numpy-arrays) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053928/very-large-matrices-using-python-and-numpy)

Comment: Are you sure you need `np.where`? Where are you using this result? Would `dmat > DIST` without `np.where` be sufficient?

Comment: Is it really necessary to generate the whole 16000x16000 matrix? If it's a distance matrix then it will be symmetric, so at most you would only need to store/search the upper or lower triangle. Could you explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve? I suspect you might be much better off using a [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query.html) instead.