# Create large random boolean matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am trying to create a huge `boolean` matrix which is randomly filled with `True` and `False` with a given probability `p`. At first I used this code:

```
N = 30000
p = 0.1
np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(N, N), p=[p, 1-p])
```

But sadly it does not seem to terminate for this big `N`. So I tried to split it up into the generation of the single rows by doing this:

```
N = 30000
p = 0.1
mask = np.empty((N, N))
for i in range (N):
     mask[i] = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=N, p=[p, 1-p])            
     if (i % 100 == 0):
          print(i)
```

Now, there happens something strange (at least on my device): The first ~1100 rows are very fastly generated - but after it, the code becomes horribly slow. Why is this happening? What do I miss here? Are there better ways to create a big matrix which has `True` entries with probability `p` and `False` entries with probability `1-p`?

**Edit**: As many of you assumed that the RAM will be a problem: As the device which will run the code has almost 500GB RAM, this won't be a problem.

Comment: Failed to understand that part - `does not seem to terminate for this big N`. Clarifications on it?

Comment: Why a boolean-array but not setting the dtype? And check iif your memory is enough. Otherwise trashing will slow down every approach.

Comment: once memory exhausted, it slows down machine?

Comment: @Serge But why? I mean: I am creating the NxN array in line 3 - so there is no reason why the memory should get exhausted. Furthermore, the memory is really no problem, as there is plenty in the machine - roughly 0.5 TB.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053928/very-large-matrices-using-python-and-numpy

Comment: @Divakar "does not seem to terminate for this big N" means that I was not able to get a result after waiting a really long time.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? 900 million elements is a lot, and NumPy creates an intermediate array of 900 million float64s to decide what elements to pick. Peak RAM usage is going to be over 8 GB.

Comment: I thought you slow down on 1100rd row, not 3rd

Comment: @Serge Yes, roughly after the 1100th rough has been generated. I meant, that I am reserving the memory for the array in line (I wrote 'row' before by accident) 3.

Comment: @FlashTek: Your OS won't actually commit RAM to that allocation until you write to it.

Comment: @user2357112 Okay, my bad. But when i change `np.empty` to `np.zeros` the RAM will be allocated, won't it? After doing this change the slowdown is happening at row 23000.

Comment: Not sure, not expert. I guess creating empty table is faster than one filled values. Anyway suggest read my link.

Comment: if you have 500GB of RAM how is your first method not being finished? I am confused...

Comment: This is slightly faster though it won't solve if there is any memory problems: `np.random.binomial(1, 1-p, size=(N, N)).astype('bool')`

Comment: @ayhan that's actually the slowest method of the 3 --> 
`CPU times: user 21 s, sys: 1.78 s, total: 22.8 s Wall time: 22.8 s`

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy I don't have enough RAM to test it with N=30000 but for N=15000 it is faster http://imgur.com/fQUbYCa

Comment: just to be sure, OS/numpy is 64 bit?

Comment: another trick is flash the cache (collect the garbage in the middle) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351255/techniques-for-working-with-large-numpy-arrays

Comment: Can you verify if the memory usage before and during execution, just to verify that the system has enough free memory. Can you share the result of `mask.dtype`, `mask.nbytes` and `mask[0][[0]].nbytes`

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy Yeah... this is confusing me just as well. The code is slowing dramatically down, so that it does not finish in time as already described.

Comment: @Serge Yes, its a 64bit setup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Really surprised no one has mentioned this solution yet..

This line

```py
np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(N, N), p=[p, 1-p])
```

runs NXN [Bernoulli Trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution). (In your case, 900M of them!) A Bernoulli trial is just a random experiment with two possible outcomes, with probabilities p and 1-p.

The sum of N Bernoulli trials, each with probability p, can be modeled by the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

We can leverage this fact to randomly simulate the total count of True elements. With NumPy,

```py
import numpy as np

N = 30000
p = 0.1

# Build a random number generator
rng = np.random.default_rng(123)

# Randomly determine the total number of True values
Ntrue = rng.binomial(n=N*N, p=p, size=1)[0]  # 90016776
```

Now we can randomly determine the *position* of each True element by randomly choosing row and col indices **without replacement**.

```py
# Randomly determine true position
position_ids = rng.choice(a=N*N, size=Ntrue, replace=False)
positions = np.unravel_index(position_ids, shape=(N,N))
```

And now we can populate a compressed sparse row (CSR) matrix.

```py
from scipy import sparse

# Build a compressed sparse row matrix with the constructor:
# csr_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), [shape=(M, N)])
result = sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones(shape=Ntrue), positions), shape=(N,N))
```

Notice this solution avoids storing *and computing* 900M boolean values.

Funny enough, I [wrote about a nearly identical problem](https://www.practiceprobs.com/problemsets/python-sparse-matrices/mine-field/) before stumbling upon this question.

Answer (score 33):

The problem is your RAM, the values are being stored in memory as it's being created. I just created this matrix using this command:

`np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(N, N), p=[p, 1-p])`

I used an `AWS i3` instance with 64GB of RAM and 8 cores. To create this matrix, `htop` shows that it takes up ~20GB of RAM. Here is a benchmark in case you care:

```
time np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(N, N), p=[p, 1-p])

CPU times: user 18.3 s, sys: 3.4 s, total: 21.7 s
Wall time: 21.7 s


 def mask_method(N, p):
    for i in range(N):
        mask[i] = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=N, p=[p, 1-p])
        if (i % 100 == 0):
            print(i)

time mask_method(N,p)

CPU times: user 20.9 s, sys: 1.55 s, total: 22.5 s
Wall time: 22.5 s
```

Note that the mask method only takes up ~9GB of RAM at it's peak.

Edit: The first method flushes the RAM after the process is done where as the function method retains all of it.

Answer (score 25):

> So I tried to split it up into the generation of the single rows by doing this:

The way that `np.random.choice` works is by first generating a `float64` in `[0, 1)` for every cell of your data, and then converting that into an index in your array using `np.search_sorted`. This intermediate representation is 8 times larger than the boolean array!

Since your data is boolean, you can get a factor of two speedup with

```
np.random.rand(N, N) > p
```

Which naturally, you could use inside your looping solution

It seems like `np.random.choice` could do with some buffering here - you might want to file an issue against numpy.

Another option would be to try and generate `float32`s instead of `float64`s. I'm not sure if numpy can do that right now, but you could request the feature.

Comment: Okay, interesting - the solution with`np.random.rand(N, N) > p` was my first idea which I discarded as I thought that the direct numpy call would be faster.

Comment: @FlashTek: Problem is that `np.random.choice` has to do more work, since it's has to handle cases with more than two outcomes. Definitely scope for a special case when the number of choices is two

Comment: Alright. But do you know why this kind of slowdown happens in my first post?

Comment: Which kind of slowdown? The reason your second attempt is faster is because you're not allocating all the floats at once, and they're much bigger than your final result.

Comment: No, I mean the slowdown in the second attempt which happens ~ after row 1100 has been generated - as described above.

Answer (score 1):

With equal distribution:

```
mask = np.random.randint(2, size=(N, N), dtype=bool)
```

[np.random.randint](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)

Comment: I arrived from a web search looking for exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility could be to generate it in a batch (i.e. compute many sub-arrays and stack them together at the very end). But, consider not to update one array (`mask`) in a `for` loop as OP is doing. This would force the whole array to load in main memory during every indexing update.

Instead for example: to get `30000x30000`, have 9000 `100x100` separate arrays, update each of this `100x100` array accordingly in a `for` loop and finally stack these 9000 arrays together in a giant array. This would definitely need not more than 4GB of RAM and would be very fast as well.

Minimal Example:

```
In [9]: a
Out[9]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])

In [10]: np.hstack([np.vstack([a]*5)]*5)
Out[10]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]])

In [11]: np.hstack([np.vstack([a]*5)]*5).shape
Out[11]: (10, 10)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use random number generator for this like:

### rng= np.random.default_rng()

### random_bools= rng.integers(0,1,(4,3),endpoint= True).astype('bool')

It will give you random boolean array of size (4,3) which you can choose according to your need.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).