# How to generate a Boolean array with random values?

Tags: python, numpy

Basically, I want to generate a boolean array with given length but the content is randomly given.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create large random boolean matrix with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528637/create-large-random-boolean-matrix-with-numpy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43528943/6116330).
Try

```
np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(N,))
```

Answer (score 1):

A faster implementation would be

```
from numpy.random import default_rng

size = 100_000
rng = default_rng()
rng.integers(0, 1, size, endpoint=True, dtype=bool)
```

On my machine

```
%timeit rng.integers(0, 1, size, endpoint=True, dtype=bool)
124 µs ± 595 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit rng.choice(a=[False, True], size=size)
937 µs ± 3.93 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Note that I used the [new random generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.Generator), [instructions here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html#random-quick-start).