# Write data to GeoTiff using GDAL without creating data array?

Tags: python, numpy, gdal

Is it possible to write data line by line using gdal's WriteArray, rather than creating and feeding it an entire array?

I've run into a `MemoryError` when creating an numpy array of size (50539,98357). I suppose I could get around this [by using PyTables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1062629/943773), but I'd rather not complicate things

```
>>> import numpy
>>> cols = 50539
>>> rows = 98357
>>> a1 = np.zeros((cols,rows))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a1 = np.zeros((cols,rows))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

**Update:**
I ended up using Abudis's solution combined with a sparse matrix in which I saved the points, pulling out each row as a "dense" or standard matrix. Comments welcome.

```
dataset = driver.Create(filename, cols, rows, number_of_bands, band_type)
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
offset = 1 # i.e. the number of rows to write with each iteration

# values, pixel_x, and pixel_y defined earlier in my script
data = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((values,(pixel_y,pixel_x)),dtype=float)

# iterate data writing for each row in data sparse array
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    data_row = data[i,:].todense() # output row of sparse array as standard array
    band.WriteArray(data_row,0,offset*i)
band.SetNoDataValue(NULL_VALUE)
band.FlushCache()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really a `gdal` expert here, but looks like this worked. So, the trick is to use `yoff` parameter of [WriteArray](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal_array-module.html) method. This way it is possible to write data to file in chunks. We basically just set the offset while writing next chunk of data.

```
import numpy as np
import gdal

cols = 50539
rows = 10000
offset = 1000

dst_filename = 'test.tif'
format = 'GTiff'
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)

dst_ds = driver.Create(dst_filename, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)

for i in range(10):
    # generate random integers from 1 to 10
    a = np.random.random_integers(1, 10, size=(offset, cols))
    # write data to band 1
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(a, 0, offset * i)

dst_ds = None
```

This yields a 50539 by 10000 pixels tiff-file. If you really need 98357 rows, I guess you can just set `offset` value to 1 and `rows` to 98357. Theoretically it should work, because it worked on smaller array (10 by 20 pixels).

**EDIT:** Don't forget to change `range(10)` to something like `range(98357)` or `xrange(98357)`