# matrix operations with gigantic matrices in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix-multiplication, adjacency-matrix

Does anybody know how to work with gigantic matrices in python? I have to work with adjacency matrices of shape (10^6,10^6) and perform operations including addition, scaling and dot product. Using numpy arrays I had problems with the ram.

Comment: That's about a terabyte of RAM assuming 1 byte values... Is your matrix sparse...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053928/python-numpy-very-large-matrices ... apparently PyTables can help ... as well as some others (http://www.h5py.org/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this...

```
import numpy as np

# Create large arrays x and y.
# Note they are 1e4 not 1e6 b/c of memory issues creating random numpy matrices (CookieOfFortune) 
# However, the same principles apply to larger arrays
x = np.random.randn(10000, 10000)
y = np.random.randn(10000, 10000)

# Create memory maps for x and y arrays
xmap = np.memmap('xfile.dat', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=x.shape)
ymap = np.memmap('yfile.dat', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=y.shape)

# Fill memory maps with data
xmap[:] = x[:]
ymap[:] = y[:]

# Create memory map for out of core dot product result
prodmap = np.memmap('prodfile.dat', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=x.shape)

# Due out of core dot product and write data
prodmap[:] = np.memmap.dot(xmap, ymap)

# Create memory map for out of core addition result
addmap = np.memmap('addfile.dat', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=x.shape)

# Due out of core addition and write data
addmap[:] = xmap + ymap

# Create memory map for out of core scaling result
scalemap = np.memmap('scalefile.dat', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=x.shape)

# Define scaling constant
scale = 1.3

# Do out of core  scaling and write data
scalemap[:] = scale * xmap
```

This code will create files xfile.dat, yfile.dat, ect that contain the arrays in binary format. To access them later you simply need to do `np.memmap(filename)`. Other arguments to `np.memmap` are optional, but reccomended (arguments like dtype, shape, ect.).