# Python on Mac Terminal - Killed: 9

Tags: python, macos, terminal, python-itertools

I wrote the following program in Python (working with a text file of 1000 words and finding all permutations of 4 words) and ran it on the Mac terminal:

```
from itertools import permutations

with open('wordlist.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.rstrip() for x in content] 

g = open("finalwordlist.txt", "a")

g.write('%s' % "\n".join(map("".join, permutations(content,4))))
```

After a short while, I got the following output from the terminal:

```
Killed: 9
```

No output was written to the output text file, so I assume the program terminated before the write() step.

This program worked when I was finding permutations of sizes less than 4 (ex. 1,2,3). Was the Killed: 9 because of the size of all the permutations? Or something to do with the Mac terminal environment?

How would I be able to work around this error? Thanks!

Comment: Check this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268471/python-killed-9-when-running-a-code-using-dictionaries-created-from-2-csv-files

Answer (score 2):

Let's see ... you've generated a single Python object of roughly 1000^4 permutations of 4 words each.  Average word length in *usage* is about 4.5 letters, but the average length of a lexicon is more -- I'll take a stab that it's more than 25 characters per permutation.  This gives you 2.5 * 10^13 bytes in your object.

How does your RAM allocation do with a single string of 250 Terabytes?
If you blow your memory limits, what is the error message?

Yes, this is an issue with you Mac environment: SegFault is *not* an error message.
It appears that your system crashed so hard, that it never got back to issue the Python memory fault.

BTW, the repair is "obvious" -- *quit trying to write 250 Tb in one call*!
There is nothing in the output differentiation that requires the block write, I hope.  Instead, write them one at a time.

```
for combo in permutations(content,4):
    g.write("".join(combo) + "\n")
```